# PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run a `cmd` file that calls a PowerShell script from `cmd.exe`, but I am getting this error:

> `Management_Install.ps1` cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.

I ran this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

When I run `Get-ExecutionPolicy` from PowerShell, it returns `Unrestricted`.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

Output:

```
Unrestricted
```

---

> cd "C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Management Portal\Install\Scripts"
> powershell .\Management_Install.ps1 1
>
> WARNING: Running x86 PowerShell...
>
> File `C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Management Portal\Install\Scripts\Management_Install.ps1` cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "`get-help about_signing`" for more details.
>
> At line:1 char:25
>
> - `.\Management_Install.ps1` <<<<  1
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
>
> C:\Projects\Microsoft.Practices.ESB\Source\Samples\Management Portal\Install\Scripts> PAUSE
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

---

The system is [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its worth pointing out that Execution Policy carries several scopes, and running PowerShell in different ways can get you different policies.  To view the list of policies, run `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List`.

Comment: All policy [explanations are here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1#parameters).

Answer (score 3509, accepted):

If you're using [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 then there is an *x64* and *x86* version of PowerShell both of which have to have their execution policies set. Did you set the execution policy on both hosts?

As an *Administrator*, you can set the execution policy by typing this into your PowerShell window:

```None
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

For more information, see *[Using the Set-ExecutionPolicy Cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy)*.

When you are done, you can set the policy back to its default value with:

```None
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

You may see an error:

```None
Access to the registry key
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. 
To change the execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, 
  start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option. 
To change the execution policy for the current user, 
  run "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".
```

So you may need to run the command like this (as seen in comments):

```None
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted` seems to be the way to undo it if you want to put the permissions back to as they were: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx.  The temporary bypass method by `@Jack Edmonds` looks safer to me: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File script.ps1`

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned cannot be the first line in your script. If it is, highlight it and run selected only INITIALLY before running the rest of your script.

Comment: I came across a similar question on SF site, ["Powershell execution policy within SQL Server”](https://serverfault.com/questions/634974/powershell-execution-policy-within-sql-server) asked Oct 10 '14.  The answers there included `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` which helped me to see the different scopes.  The cmd `Get-ExecutionPolicy` does not show all the scopes.  `Import-Module SQLPS` is now working with policies changed as follows: `{Undefined- Process,MachinePolicy,UserPolicy,}; {RemoteSigned- CurrentUser, LocalMachine}`.

Comment: If I do this, does the change last for only the duration of the current PowerShell? Or is it bigger than that?

Comment: Also be sure to execute it in a direct Powershell shell, and not a cmd shell. It won't take effect otherwise.

Comment: If you need it less restricted than `RemoteSigned`, you can also set it to `Unrestricted`.

Comment: After this Command  get Success        Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: @SharpC, it is `Undefined` that reverts the policy in a given scope to its default; e.g., `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Undefined -Force`. While on workstation editions of Windows using `Restricted` has the same effect, note that - at least nowadays - server editions default to `RemoteSigned`.

Comment: In powershell
# To check the current execution policy, use the following command:
Get-ExecutionPolicy

# To change the execution policy to Unrestricted, which allows running any script without digital signatures, use the following command:
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

# This solution worked for me, but be careful of the security risks involved.

Comment: this line works for me, thanks.
"Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser"

Answer (score 1130):

You can bypass this policy for a single file by adding `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` when running PowerShell

```None
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1
```

Comment: This is also really handy if you're on a non-administrator account. I made a shortcut to `%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass` on my taskbar.

Comment: Note that Microsoft Technet stylizes it as "Bypass", not "ByPass". See: https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/hh849812.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get the same permission denied as if I called it normally.  Calling a ps1 from a .bat by doing `type script.ps1 | powershell -` does work though.

Comment: The purpose to Execution Policy is to prevent people from double-clicking a `.ps1` and accidentally running something they didn't mean to. This would happen with `.bat` files

Comment: Perfect solution for single file execution, without changing policies and lowering security.

Comment: `A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'` Command: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\file.ps1`

Comment: ```powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\file.ps1```
  This will work @Devil'sAdvocate

Comment: This worked for me but my antivirus flagged it as malicious and quarantined it. I had to add an exception.

Comment: This doesn't work for me when using winsw to run the ps1 file as a service.  I get the same error in the log.

Comment: How do I do that permanently for one file

Answer (score 395):

I had a similar issue and noted that the default `cmd` on [Windows Server 2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2012), was running the x64 one.

For **Windows 11**, **Windows 10**, **Windows 7**, **Windows 8**, **Windows Server 2008 R2** or **Windows Server 2012**, run the following commands as **Administrator**:

*x86* (32 bit)
Open `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe`
Run the command `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

*x64* (64 bit)
Open `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`
Run the command `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

You can check mode using

- In CMD: `echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%`
- In Powershell: `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess`

**References:**
[MSDN - Windows PowerShell execution policies](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847748.aspx)
[Windows - 32bit vs 64bit directory explanation](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm)

Comment: Is it possible to run these via powershell passing the arguments to the cmd executable so as to automate the configuration?

Comment: @openCivilisation Could you not run a .cmd file with the above command, before executing the powershell? You can also set this at the policy level if you need to, although I have not done that.

Answer (score 258):

Most of the existing answers explain the *How*, but very few explain the *Why*. And before you go around executing code from strangers on the Internet, especially code that disables security measures, you should understand exactly what you're doing. So here's a little more detail on this problem.

From the TechNet [About Execution Policies Page](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847748.aspx):

> Windows PowerShell execution policies let you determine the conditions under which Windows PowerShell loads configuration files and runs scripts.

The benefits of which, as enumerated by [PowerShell Basics - Execution Policy and Code Signing](http://www.darkoperator.com/blog/2013/3/5/powershell-basics-execution-policy-part-1.html), are:

> - **Control of Execution** - Control the level of trust for executing scripts.
> - **Command Highjack** - Prevent injection of commands in my path.
> - **Identity** - Is the script created and signed by a developer I trust and/or a signed with a certificate from a Certificate Authority I trust.
> - **Integrity** - Scripts cannot be modified by malware or malicious user.

To check your current execution policy, you can run [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849821.aspx). But you're probably here because you want to change it.

To do so you'll run the [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849812.aspx) cmdlet.

You'll have two major decisions to make when updating the execution policy.

#### Execution Policy Type:

- **`Restricted`**<sup>†</sup> - No Script either local, remote or downloaded can be executed on the system.
- **`AllSigned`** - All script that are ran require to be digitally signed.
- **`RemoteSigned`** - All remote scripts (UNC) or downloaded need to be signed.
- **`Unrestricted`** - No signature for any type of script is required.

#### Scope of new Change

- **`LocalMachine`**<sup>†</sup> - The execution policy affects all users of the computer.
- **`CurrentUser`** - The execution policy affects only the current user.
- **`Process`** - The execution policy affects only the current Windows PowerShell process.

<sup>† = Default</sup>

*For example*: if you wanted to change the policy to RemoteSigned for just the CurrentUser, you'd run the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

**Note**: In order to change the Execution policy, you must be running **PowerShell As Administrator**.
If you are in regular mode and try to change the execution policy, you'll get the following error:

> Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. To change the execution policy for the default (LocalMachine) scope, start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as administrator" option.

If you want to tighten up the internal restrictions on your own scripts that have not been downloaded from the Internet (or at least don't contain the UNC metadata), you can force the policy to only run signed scripts.  To sign your own scripts, you can follow the instructions on Scott Hanselman's article on [Signing PowerShell Scripts](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx).

**Note**: Most people are likely to get this error whenever they open PowerShell because the first thing PowerShell tries to do when it launches is execute your user profile script that sets up your environment however you like it.

The file is typically located in:

```
%UserProfile%\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

You can find the exact location by running the PowerShell variable

```
$profile
```

If there's nothing that you care about in the profile, and don't want to fuss with your security settings, you can just delete it and PowerShell won't find anything that it cannot execute.

Comment: I feel like it's important to note that while execution policy is a security measure, it's not one that's intended to prevent users from executing PowerShell code.  Execution policy is something that's intended to *protect your scripts* and determine who wrote, modifed or approved them and that's all.  It's trivial to [get around execution policy](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/) with something as simple as `Get-Content .\MyFile.ps1 | powershell.exe -NoProfile -`.

Comment: Given the existence of `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` though, what is the purpose of this policy anyway? Is it just to prevent users from accidentally opening a powershell console and running a malicious script? Couldn't the attacker just use an executable or a batch script if they wanted to get around this? Even after reading @BaconBits comment I'm not quite sure what scenario this policy is meant to prevent...

Comment: @Ajedi32 Say I have a task that runs a script on a network share.  When I invoke my script, I want my process to verify that the script is signed.  I want my code to double check that the script I'm going to run is the code I trust to run.  I don't care if you can run my code.  Stopping that is access rights' job.  I just want to prevent you from making me run code that I didn't write.  Access rights means the operating system prevents you from modifying my code when you're logged on.  Code signing and execution policy means my script hasn't been modified when *I* go to run it.

Comment: how about showing how to sign the script rather then how to disable security? Is that an option?

Comment: @gman, I think that's a fair point. To crowdsource the work, you can certainly add that answer or append to this one.

Comment: @Ajedi32 If there are similar policies to prevent running unsigned exe and/or forbidding running bat scripts, then that would prevent a user from accidentally running any unsigned code, which could be useful. Running it then becomes intentional and clear that this is unsigned code (which of course is not really super helpful in itself to determine if you should run it...).

Answer (score 73):

We can get the status of current `ExecutionPolicy` by the command below:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

By default it is **Restricted**. To allow the execution of PowerShell scripts we need to set this ExecutionPolicy either as **Unrestricted** or **Bypass**.

We can set the policy for Current User as `Bypass` by using any of the below PowerShell commands:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force
```

**Unrestricted** policy loads all configuration files and runs all scripts. If you run an unsigned script that was downloaded from the Internet, you are prompted for permission before it runs.

Whereas in **Bypass** policy, nothing is blocked and there are no warnings or prompts during script execution. Bypass `ExecutionPolicy` is more relaxed than `Unrestricted`.

Comment: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force;`

AKA quick and dirty way to tell VS2015 to stop complaining and run my bloody script. thanks. lifesaver.

Comment: The trailing semicolons on the ends of your commands are superfluous.

Answer (score 67):

Also running this command before the script also solves the issue:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: -1 - Follow the principle of least permission.  At least set the policy to `RemoteSigned` before removing all restrictions on your security policy.  If that doesn't work, then re-assess what your pain points are and why it isn't working.  You can set `unrestricted` as a last resort, but it shouldn't be your starting point.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this option too. With all due respect to security needs for production purposes, in the times when quick prototyping ability demand is so high, all the policies and security really get in the way of getting stuff done.

Comment: Regarding the comment re prototyping, I'm afraid that this is why crappy code gets into production. Of course this is just a trivial example, but if you can't solve something this trivial during development, it's a worry for release. Also, for bespoke code, and if you can, know the target environment - we set the majority of our internal systems as `Remotesigned`.

Answer (score 59):

If you are in an environment where you are not an administrator, you can set the Execution Policy just for you (`CurrentUser`), and it will not require administrator.

You can set it to `RemoteSigned`:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"
```

or `Unrestricted`:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted"
```

You can read all about Getting and Setting Execution policy in the help entries:

```
Help Get-ExecutionPolicy -Full
Help Set-ExecutionPolicy -Full
```

Comment: Worked great for me in Windows 8, even when `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` as an admin didn't seem to "unrestrict" enough to actually help.

Comment: I believe what you may be experiencing is a GPO or something else overwriting your setting of the "LocalMachine" level of ExecutionPolicy. You cannot overwrite what a Domain Policy has in place with the Set-ExecutionPolicy command. However, but setting the "CurrentUser" level of access, you and only you will have the specified Execution Policy. This is because the computer looks at the CurrentUser for execution policy before it looks at the LocalMachine setting.

Answer (score 55):

In Windows 7:

Go to Start Menu and search for "Windows PowerShell ISE".

Right click the x86 version and choose "Run as administrator".

In the top part, paste `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`; run the script. Choose "Yes".

Repeat these steps for the 64-bit version of Powershell ISE too (the non x86 version).

I'm just clarifying the steps that @Chad Miller hinted at.  Thanks Chad!

Comment: In Windows 8 too, this worked. I set  Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; in Windows Powershell only, by running it as administrator. Didn't need to repeat the procedure for x86 version.

Answer (score 42):

RemoteSigned: all scripts you created yourself will be run, and all scripts downloaded from the Internet will need to be signed by a trusted publisher.

OK, change the policy by simply typing:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: As recommended in other posts: it's wise to include "-Scope CurrentUser" for a more secure policy, when that makes sense.

Answer (score 36):

First, you need to open the PowerShell window and run this command.

`set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Then it will ask you to confirm. Type <kbd>Y</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

When you run this command, you can see that your system has set all policies for the current user as remotely. It will take a few seconds to complete this process.

The image will be shown like below:

[image]

To check if the execution policy has set. Type:

`Get-ExecutionPolicy`

If it was set, the output would be like this:

[image]

Answer (score 32):

I'm using **Windows 10** and was unable to run any command. The only command that gave me some clues was this:

[x64]

> 1. Open C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe *[as administrator]*
> 2. Run the command> **powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

But this didn't work. It was limited. Probably new security policies for Windows10. I had this error:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy: Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope. Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of...

So I found another way (**solution**):

1. Open Run Command/Console (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
2. Type: **gpedit.msc** ([Group Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) Editor)
3. Browse to *Local Computer Policy* -> *Computer Configuration* -> *Administrative Templates* -> *Windows Components* -> *Windows Powershell*.
4. Enable "**Turn on Script Execution**"
5. Set the policy as needed. I set mine to "**Allow all scripts**".

Now open PowerShell and enjoy ;)

Comment: Is this a stand-alone installation, or are you connected to a workgroup or domain?

Comment: Why open cmd to do it? Just open ISE (as admin) and type `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Comment: OMG this finally fixed my win10 box, @kolob set-executionpolicy is not enough

Comment: You should not be using `Unrestricted`. It is better practice to use `RemoteSigned`

Comment: @xer0x it should be as long as you run powershell as an administrator

Comment: This answer solves my issue. Thanks. Another answers doesn't work for me.

Comment: This actually solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

Open a Windows PowerShell command window and run the below query to change `ExecutionPolicy`:

**`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`**

If it asks for confirming changes, press <kbd>Y</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 21):

You should run this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Comment: This is the _exact_ same as [@Micah 'Powershell Ninja''s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20080077/3025856) from _eight years ago_. And, for that matter, it's effectively covered by [@KyleMit's exceptional accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26955050/3025856) from seven years ago. Before submitting a new answer, please review the existing answer and upvote ones you find useful. _Only submit a new answer to established questions if you have something **new and substantial** to add to the existing answers_.

Comment: Life saver. Works, thanks

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type copy paste command and press <kbd>OK</kbd>:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"
```

And execute your script.

Then revert changes like:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "AllSigned"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, these 2 lines are answers for Win10 in 2022

Answer (score 14):

Open the command prompt in Windows.
If the problem is only with PowerShell, use the following command:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"
```

Answer (score 14):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

This worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 11):

Setting the execution policy is environment-specific. If you are trying to execute a script from the running x86 [ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) you have to use the x86 PowerShell to set the execution policy. Likewise, if you are running the 64-bit ISE you have to set the policy with the 64-bit PowerShell.

Answer (score 11):

1. Open Run Command/Console ( Win + R )
   Type: **gpedit. msc** (Group Policy Editor)
2. Browse to **Local Computer Policy** -> **Computer Configuration** -> **Administrative Templates** -> **Windows Components** -> **Windows Powershell.**
3. **Enable** "**Turn on Script Execution**"
   Set the policy as needed. **I set mine to "Allow all scripts"**.

Now run the run command what ever you are using.. Trust this the app will runs.. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 10):

You can also bypass this by using the following command:

```
powershell Get-Content .\test.ps1 | Invoke-Expression
```

You can also read this article by Scott Sutherland that explains 15 different ways to bypass the PowerShell `Set-ExecutionPolicy` if you don't have administrator privileges:

*[15 Ways to Bypass the PowerShell Execution Policy](https://blog.netspi.com/15-ways-to-bypass-the-powershell-execution-policy/)*

Comment: This is  probably one of the more compelling guides to troubleshoot and understand this restriction.

Answer (score 10):

you may try this and select "All" Option

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Answer (score 10):

I have also faced a similar issue. Try this.

As I'm using Windows, I followed the steps as given below.
Open a command prompt as an administrator and then go to this path:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm\
```

Look for the file ng.ps1 in this folder (directory)
and then delete it (*del ng.ps1*).

You can also clear npm cache after this though it should work without this step as well.

Comment: this one worked, i just removed a few .ps1 extension files and it started working

Answer (score 9):

If you have Git installed, just use [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway).

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Executing this command in administrator mode in PowerShell will solve the problem.

Answer (score 8):

There's great information in the existing answers, but let me attempt a **systematic overview**:

#### Context

PowerShell's effective **[execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) applies**:

- to **PowerShell code stored in *files***, which means regular script files (`.ps1`), script *module* files (`.psm1`), as well as [formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Format.ps1xml) and [type-extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Types.ps1xml) files (`.psm1xml`).

  - It does *not* apply to:

    - calls to (binary) *cmdlets* (e.g., `Get-ChildItem`)
    - commands submitted interactively or passed to the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) via the
      `-Command` parameter (unless these commands directly or indirectly call script files as defined above).
- **on Windows only** (that is, on *Unix-like* platforms (Linux, macOS) execution policies do not apply and *no* restrictions are placed on executing PowerShell code)

On *workstation* editions of Windows, script-file execution is *disabled* by default (policy `Restricted`), requiring either a *persistent* modification of the policy to enable it, or a *current-process-only* modification such as via the `-ExecutionPolicy` parameter when calling the PowerShell *CLI*, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) (*Windows PowerShell* edition) / [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) (*PowerShell (Core)* edition).

Execution **policies are maintained *separately***:

- for the two **PowerShell *editions***:

  - the legacy, *Windows-only*, ships-with-Windows *Windows PowerShell* edition (whose latest and last version is v5.1.x)
  - the modern, *cross-platform*, install-on-demand [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition (v6+).
- for the ***32-bit and 64-bit* versions** of *Windows PowerShell* (both of which are preinstalled)

  - Note: If you were to install 32-bit and 64-bit versions of *PowerShell (Core)* side by side (which would be unusual), only the `LocalMachine` scope would be bitness-specific.

For a given edition / bitness combination of PowerShell, the **execution policies can be set in *multiple scopes***, but **there's only ever *one effective* policy**, based on precedence rules - see below.

#### Details

- **In PowerShell *on Windows*, script-file execution is *disabled* by default** in ***workstation* editions** of Windows (on Unix, execution policies do not apply); that is, the default execution policy in workstation editions of Windows is **`Restricted`**, whereas in ***server* editions**, it is **`RemoteSigned`**; see the conceptual [about_Execution_Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) help topic for a description of all available policies.
- To set a (local) policy that permits script execution, use **[`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy)**. There are **three scopes** that `Set-ExecutionPolicy` can target, using the **`-Scope` parameter** (see below); **changing the `LocalMachine` scope requires *elevation* (running as admin)**.

  - To *unset* a previously set policy in a given scope, use `Undefined`
- **A frequently used policy that provides a balance between security and convenience is `RemoteSigned`**, which allows *local* scripts - including from *network shares* - to execute *without containing a [signature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Signing)*, while requiring scripts downloaded *from the internet* to be signed (assuming that the downloading mechanism marks such as scripts as internet-originated, which web browsers do by default). For instance, **to set the current user's execution policy to `RemoteSigned`**, run the following:

  ```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force
  ```
- The **PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh)** (`powershell.exe` for *Windows PowerShell*, `pwsh.exe` for *PowerShell (Core)*, v6+) accepts a process-specific `-ExecutionPolicy <policy>` argument too, which is often used for ***ad-hoc* policy overrides** (only for the process being created, the equivalent of `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process ..`); e.g.:

  ```
  pwsh.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File someScript.ps1
  ```
- **Important**:

  - Execution policies can also be set via **[Group Policy Objects (GPOs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy)**, in which case they **can *not* be changed or overridden with `Set-ExecutionPolicy` or via the CLI**: see [about_Group_Policy_Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Group_Policy_Settings)
  - Execution policies can be set in **various scopes**, and which one is in effect is determined by their **precedence** (run [`Get-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/Get-ExecutionPolicy) `-List` to see all scopes and their respective policies), in **descending order**:

    - `MachinePolicy` (via GPO; cannot be overridden locally)<sup>[1]</sup>
    - `UserPolicy` (via GPO; cannot be overridden locally)<sup>[1]</sup>
    - `Process` (current process only; typically set ad-hoc via the CLI)
    - `CurrentUser` (as set by `Set-ExecutionPolicy`)
    - `LocalMachine` (as set by `Set-ExecutionPolicy`, with admin rights)

---

<sup>[1] This applies to *domain*-wide GPOs. *Local* GPOs *can*  be modified locally, namely via `gpedit.msc` or directly via the registry.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

In the PowerShell [ISE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315244.aspx) editor I found running the following line first allowed scripts.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
```

Answer (score 7):

In Window 10:

If you are not administrator, you can use this:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser

cmdlet Set-ExecutionPolicy at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
ExecutionPolicy: `RemoteSigned`
```

It solved my problem like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

For Windows 11...

It is indeed very easy. Just open the settings application.
Navigate to *Privacy and Security*:

[image: Privacy and security image]

Click on *For Developers* and scroll to the bottom and find the PowerShell option under which check the checkbox stating "Change the execution policy ... remote scripts".

[image: Developer options image]

Comment: This option was checked by default on my relatively fresh install of Win11 and didn't work for me until I also ran the `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` as well (or whatever security level is needed from `Set-ExecutionPolicy`). I was simply trying to run `truffle version`. "Show settings" next to that option, simply takes you to a syntax helper ps prompt where I ran that `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run **Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser**
2. Provide **RemoteSigned** and press Enter
3. Run **Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser**
4. Provide **Unrestricted** and press Enter

Answer (score 5):

In powershell

To check the current execution policy, use the following command:

`Get-ExecutionPolicy`

To change the execution policy to Unrestricted, which allows running any script without digital signatures, use the following command:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

This solution worked for me, but be careful of the security risks involved.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows 10, enable the option under the name: 'Install apps from any source, including loose files.'

[image]

It fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

Open PowerShell as a administrator. Run the following command

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

Type Y when asked!

Comment: This worked in Windows 11

Comment: This is identical to numerous other answers suggesting the same exact command, one of which is the [highest-voted, accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038991/150605).  You really should check that you're not duplicating other answers before posting your own.  I realize that's no small task on a question with **47 answers** (and counting), but if people would **stop posting the same answer** over and over there wouldn't be so many answers to sift through!

Answer (score 4):

To fix this issue, we have to set the execution policy, so that the PowerShell script runs on the particular machine. Here is how:

Open PowerShell Console by selecting “Run as Administrator” and set the execution Policy with the command: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Type “Y” when prompted to proceed

credits:
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/03/fix-for-powershell-script-cannot-be-loaded-because-running-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system.html

Answer (score 4):

Solution for “cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system“:
How do you enable running scripts is disabled on this system error? To fix this issue, we have to set the execution policy, so that the PowerShell script runs on the particular machine. Here is to permit PowerShell script execution:

1. Open PowerShell Console by selecting “Run as Administrator” and get the execution Policy with the command: Get-ExecutionPolicy to get the current policy applied, such as “Restricted”.
   [image]
2. Set the execution Policy with the following command: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
3. Type “Y” when prompted to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell 2.0, the execution policy was set to disabled by default.

From then on, the PowerShell team has made a lot of improvements, and they are confident that users will not break things much while running scripts. So from PowerShell 4.0 onward, it is enabled by default.

In your case, type `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` from the PowerShell console and say yes.

Answer (score 3):

I get another warning when I tryit to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

**I solved with this commands**

```bsh
Set-ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned" -Scope Process -Confirm:$false

Set-ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned" -Scope CurrentUser -Confirm:$false
```

Answer (score 3):

In VS code just run this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser Unrestricted
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this line worked best for one of my [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) R2 servers. A couple of others had no issues without this line in my PowerShell scripts:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -Scope Process
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the registry path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell` and set `ExecutionPolicy` to `RemoteSigned`.

Comment: 1. Open PowerShell as Administrator and run **Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser**

2. Provide **RemoteSigned** and press Enter

3. Run **Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser**

4. Provide **Unrestricted** and press Enter

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today. 64-bit execution policy was unrestricted, while 32-bit was restricted.

Here's how to change just the 32-bit policy remotely:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servername -ConfigurationName Microsoft.PowerShell32 -scriptblock {Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted}
```

Answer (score 2):

Open the Powershell console as an administrator, and then set the execution policy

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Remotesigned
```

Comment: This is identical to numerous other answers suggesting an equivalent `Set-ExecutionPolicy` command, one of which is the [highest-voted, accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038991/150605). You really should check that you're not duplicating other answers before posting your own. I realize that's no small task on a question with **40+** answers, but if people would **stop posting the same answer** over and over there wouldn't be so many answers to sift through!

Answer (score 2):

**I was facing a similar kind of error:**

*cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.*

[image]

And did this and it is fixed:

1. Open Windows powershell as administrator.
2. RUn command: `powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
3. Check status: `Get-ExecutionPolicy`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're here because of running it with [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) or [Chef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chef_%28software%29) and using `` system execution, execute as follows:

```
`powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command [Environment]::GetFolderPath(\'mydocuments\')`
```

That command is for getting "MyDocuments" Folder.

`-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` does the trick.

I hope it's helpful for someone else.

Comment: Should the enclosing `` really be there?

Answer (score 1):

Several answers point to execution policy.  However some things require "runas administrator" also.  This is safest in that there is no permanent change to execution policy, and can get past administrator restriction. Use with schedtask to start a batch with:

```
    runas.exe /savecred /user:administrator powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File script.ps1
```

from both Jack Edmonds above, and Peter Mortensen / Dhana of post [How to run an application as "run as administrator" from the command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-application-as-run-as-administrator-from-the-command-prompt)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special way to bypass it:

```
Get-Content "PS1scriptfullpath.ps1" | Powershell -NoProfile -
```

It pipes the content of PowerShell script to powershell.exe and executes it bypassing the execution policy.

Comment: What is "special" about this way?  What if arguments need to be passed to `PS1scriptfullpath.ps1`?  When/Why would one use this instead of directly launching a new PowerShell process with an overridden execution policy as shown [in this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9167524/150605) or using `-Command "PS1scriptfullpath.ps1"`?

Answer (score 1):

Delete the *ng.ps1* file in *C:\Users[your user]\AppData\Roaming\npm*.

And delete the npm cache file in *C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming*.

Answer (score 1):

in my case it happened because i use PowerShell and I should use the cmd prompt

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well. For me, the solution was simple. I didn't realize that the path in the command prompt to run [Nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) was different to where I installed the package.

So it gave me the same error that you've mentioned.

Changing my path resolved it.

Comment: What is "nodemon" and, since the author of the question hasn't indicated they're using it, how does it relate to this question?  It's not clear what the problem and solution with the path were, either.  Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63423584/150605) is more appropriate for the solution you're trying to provide.

Answer (score 0):

For a downloaded file, right-click → *Properties*

[image]

Then click *Unblock* and click <kbd>OK</kbd>. Then run the PowerShell script and it will no longer complain about not being able to run.

Answer (score 0):

A best practice is to read the script's code and verify it's safe before using the Unblock-File cmdlet. The Unblock-File cmdlet unblocks scripts so they can run, but doesn't change the execution policy.
PS> Unblock-File -Path .\Start-ActivityTracker.ps1

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.4

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for solutions related to authorizations and came across this page. I solved my problem as explained in this link. Maybe it can help someone.

```html
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

[‘Running Scripts is Disabled’ Error When Deploying on Vercel](https://medium.com/@amangupta99344/solving-the-running-scripts-is-disabled-error-when-deploying-on-vercel-65d142df06bf)

Answer (score -1):

Open cmd instead of powershell. This helped for me...

Comment: The command prompt used in the question already _is_ `cmd.exe`: "I am trying to run a `cmd` file that calls a PowerShell script from `cmd.exe` ...".  This is why the command is prefixed with `powershell`: `powershell .\Management_Install.ps1 1`.  Otherwise, "fixing" a PowerShell error by simply not using PowerShell is not a solution.

Comment: right, my fault. Did not see it. "Don't use powershell" is a bad solution to this problem, although it's a very good solution to a happier life.

Answer (score -1):

Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` command

Comment: This is identical to numerous other answers suggesting the same exact command, one of which is the [highest-voted, accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038991/150605).  You really should check that you're not duplicating other answers before posting your own.  I realize that's no small task on a question with **40+ answers**, but if people would **stop posting the same answer** over and over there wouldn't be so many answers to sift through!

Answer (score -2):

Run `cmd` or `powershell` as "`Run as administrator`"

Comment: It isn't to do with running as an admin or not.

Answer (score -3):

Open the PowerShell window as an **Administrator**. It will work.

Comment: It did not works.  However, running
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
did works.