# PowerShell on Windows 7: Set-ExecutionPolicy for regular users

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I want to run PowerShell scripts on Windows 7 as a regular user. Whenever I try, I get the following error:

```
File C:\Users\danv\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because the
execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for
more details.
At line:1 char:2
+ . <<<<  'C:\Users\danv\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Attempting to solve via `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` fails:

```
PS C:\Users\danv> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key
'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell'
is denied.
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  Unrestricted
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

I can run the `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` command as administrator, but this doesn't seem to propagate to non-administrator users.

How can I successfully run scripts as a non-administrator?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you (or a helpful admin) runs `Set-ExecutionPolicy` as administrator, the policy will be set for all users. (I would suggest "remoteSigned" rather than "unrestricted" as a safety measure.)

NB.: On a 64-bit OS you need to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy` for 32-bit and 64-bit PowerShell separately.

Comment: One comment for 64-bit Windows 8, you must execute it from an elevated PowerShell window like so: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force` followed by `start-job { Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force } -RunAs32`.
That's the only way to ensure that both versions are addressed.

Answer (score 147):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

This will set the execution policy for the current user (stored in HKEY_CURRENT_USER) rather than the local machine (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE). This is useful if you don't have administrative control over the computer.

`RemoteSigned` is a safer execution policy than `Unrestricted`. If you download a script and `RemoteSigned` is preventing you from executing it, then after vetting the script, remove the restriction by opening the file's properties and flagging "Unblock". If this is infeasible, then you can set the policy to `Unrestricted` instead.

Comment: Perfect. This solved my problem immediately. It's sort of frustrating for new users that powershell is advertised as a scripting languague that by default disallows scripting.

Comment: "Unrestricted"? Be aware of [the security implications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system/26955050#26955050).

Comment: This `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser` command solved my problem.❤

Answer (score 8):

This should solve your problem, you should try to run the following below:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 1):

If your the administrator of your pc, you can type out the following command in your

```
 Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

powershell window. You might have to run the shell as an administrator.

Once you have done that, it will ask you for the confirmation,
If you want to set the unrestricted setting for all the global users, enter 'A'
If you want to set the unrestricted setting only for current user(Admin), enter 'Y'

Remember:- You can always revert the changes you made with the following command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

Answer (score 0):

````
Select ***Start > All Programs > Windows PowerShell version > Windows PowerShell***.
Type ```Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned``` to set the policy to ```RemoteSigned```.
Type ```Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted``` to set the policy to ```Unrestricted```.
Type ```Get-ExecutionPolicy``` to verify the current settings for the execution policy.
Type ```Exit```.
````