# Browser Hangs Executing PHP that runs a Powershell

Tags: php, powershell, exec, shell-exec

I am trying to run a simple PHP that runs a powershell script, 
if I use this code I get the results in a command window, but I get an empty array in the browser:

```
<?php 
exec("powershell C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\my_shell.ps1 < NUL", $output);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

I believe the NUL will discard the output, however it works in the browser found it on [this Fourm][1]

If I use this code, without the **NUL** I will get the results on a command window but if I run the script in the browser will keep loading forever and it will never give me any results:

```
exec("powershell C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\emsrDev\\manual_shell.ps1", $output);
```

Same results if I do it this way:

```
$output = shell_exec("powershell C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\emsrDev\\manual_shell.ps1");
```

The powershell Script runs fine if I ran it independently:

```
$cmd = "cmd.exe";
&$cmd "/C echo update tasks set last='manual' where id='8'; | sqlplus vvv/www@xxx";
```

So I need to execute this in a browser and get the output.

Comment: Insufficient information.  Please post the code that the `powershell` command is running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5319219/763026  -- look here. Microsoft recommends running Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine. This allows all user accounts on a machine to run local scripts without issue, but requires confirmation to run scripts downloaded from the internet.

Comment: @SeeSharp The execution Policy works fine, I can run the script directly from powershell, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The powershell process isn't terminating, which causes the browser to hang. Add the following to the end of your script

```
Stop-Process -processname powershell*
```