# What are other kinds of fetching remote URL contents with PHP?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents, fread, fsockopen

Are there any other kinds of fetching remote data in PHP, except for: `"cURL"` and having `"allow_url_fopen"` in **php.ini** set to `"On"`, to be able to stream remote content using `"fopen"`, `"fsockopen"` or `"file_get_contents"`?

I'm working on a custom-PHP remote content streamer and I'm looking for any other ways of streaming remote content, if the `"cURL"` or `"allow_url_fopen"` is `"Off"`.

Comment: I use `file_get_contents` all the time, why aren't you using that?

Comment: I agree but it can't be used without allow_url_fopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about running system calls? Like `passthru()` or `exec()` or `system()` and calling `curl` or [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) on the command line and capturing the data

Linux Example:

```
ob_start();
passthru("wget -U 'CustomUserAgent' -q -O - 'http://www.example.com/'");
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

Windows 7+ Example (through powershell). Taken from [here](https://superuser.com/a/330754/147810)

```
(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.example.come','C:\tmp\output.tx‌​t') –
```

To expand on the windows method, see [executing a Powershell script from php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317315/executing-a-powershell-script-from-php)

Comment: this will do good only on UNIX/Linux/MAC Operating Systems, and if Windows has installed CygWin or something similar what supports "wget". I'll use this as an fail-safe exception if cURL or "allow_url_fopen" are not available. Thanks mate! +1 & accepted!

Comment: @Zlatan you could possibly achieve it on Windows 7 and above through powershell. I've updated my answer and included some of that info.

Answer (score 1):

"allow_url_fopen" does not affect "fsockopen".

Even if it did, having system calls enabled in a webserver is a security threat bigger than having "allow_url_fopen=On".

To disable fsockopen, it can be added to "disable_functions" in php.ini