# How to execute powershell script in 64 bit machine?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have written a powershell script and send to my team mates.

One of my teammate when he was right click and [Run with powershell] execute the script it did not work.

He told that it is Win7 64 bit machine.

Then i manually opened 32 bit Powershell and use the "`Powershell -file <Filename>`" and executed.

In 64 bit environment, can't we simply execute by right click and Run with powershell?

Comment: @Christian: I am using PowerCLI snapin. This is my first line "Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue".  I applied your answer but still it fails. When i right click and run with powershell it vanish. (if i run in Powershell_ise , it simply says failed)

Comment: the command 'Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core' run in console works?

Comment: What's the (recursive) content of the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1`?

Answer (score 4):

If for some reason your script can run only in x86 architecture add this at start in your script:

```
if ($env:Processor_Architecture -ne "x86")   
 {
      write-warning "Running PowerShell x86"   
         &"$env:windir\syswow64\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -noninteractive -noprofile -file $myinvocation.Mycommand.path -executionpolicy bypass   
         exit   
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647429/powershell-on-windows-7-set-executionpolicy-for-regular-users  Actual problem was as same as mentioned in the link. It solved my issue.