# Using Powershell as terminal in IntelliJ IDEA IDEs like PyCharm, PHPStorm or RubyMine

Tags: powershell, intellij-idea, pycharm

I have been attempting to run powershell as my terminal on windows in pycharm, so I did the following:

[image]

However, when I try this, it says that it cannot execute my scripts, and hence I get the following error: `SecurityError` and the Fully Qualified Id is : `UnAuthorizedAccess`.

This arises from the fact that pycharm's terminal cannot execute my `Powershell_profile.ps1` profile file.

How can I successfully run Pycharm's terminal with Powershell?

What I have tried so far, is going into my main powershell directory as in `%windir%/system32/WindowsPowerShell/1.0/profile.ps1`, and then change it to include the following:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

However, this does not help, and I get the same error when I try to open of pycharm's terminal.

I have also tried to run pycharm as Admin, however this does not solve the problem either, and I get the *same* aforementioned error.

Comment: Have you tried to specify absolute path to `powershell.exe`?

Comment: @AndreyMyatlyuk Tried as you've suggested, same problem as above.

Comment: Since it is definitely [doable](https://codeaweso.me/2013/12/cygwin-terminal-with-intellij-idea-13/), to set PowerShell as default terminal, I think it is Windows permissions issue, rather than PyCharm issue. Checkout this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647429/powershell-on-windows-7-set-executionpolicy-for-regular-users

Comment: You _can_ set it as your default terminal, however you get errors like the ones I mentioned above, and you cannot execute your profile scripts or your plugins.

Comment: This issue can **silently** prevent a user from running a virtual environment.

Comment: Please note a simple but an important step, which I initially missed so the problem didn't just go away, that I found necessary along with the others steps listed in the answers: close (click a cross) near the "Local" in the IDE's terminal window, and reopen the window. Without this simple step the terminal remained unresponsive, showing the same error messages. Apparently, you need to recreate the terminal instance. Just like reopening regular cmd in windows after changing environment variables, etc. 

Had to do this because just an IDE restart didn't fix the problem.

Comment: PowerShell is included on the Terminal options by clicking the "Down" arrow after the "+" sign within PyCharm Terminal tab. My Build is 231.8109.197 so all versions after that one should also have the native option to open PowerShell instead of a new "cmd" Terminal.

Answer (score 64):

I've replaced cmd.exe with powershell.exe in a simpler way and hope it can help.
I'm using webstorm2017 and Win10 os.

1.Find the exact location of `powershell.exe`.In mine and I believe in most computers the location would be `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.Copy the whole path into your clipboard.

2.In your IDE open File=>Setting=>Tools=>Terminal, and paste the path into "Shell path" blank.

3.Restart the IDE and everything would be ok.

Comment: Start Directory: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\; Shell path: powershell.exe for IntelliJ products of version 2017.

Comment: This makes my life so much easier.

Comment: Do not need to restart the IDE, just launch a new terminal.

Comment: Powershell is already in system path so just enter "powershell.exe" without path.

Answer (score 35):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

Comment: This works. Weird thing is the execution policy isn't read from system. IntelliJ defines its own.

Answer (score 17):

1. I updated the powershell.exe path in IntelliJ -> Settings -> Terminal
2. Opened a powershell instance in Admin mode.
3. Executed `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`
4. Restarted IntelliJ and the issue was solved.

Step 3 is from [ebelanger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25570798/4076315).

[image: Screenshot of application settings. Shows the Shell path, the Tab name (Local), and all the options below are checked.]

Answer (score 9):

Browse to the PowerShell executable, right-click, run as administrator.

From the prompt, use the same command you tried:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Once that is done, close PowerShell, and attempt to use it again from your application.

**Note:**
You can't set the execution policy from a script, as the default execution policy prevents you from running scripts. (even if it's the profile script - still a script)

Answer (score 7):

In PyCharm

File->Settings->Tools->Terminal

Shell path:
"powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass"

Then restart PyCharm

Answer (score 5):

In the Default Shell TextBox you can append the execution policy command line option like so:

powershell.exe -Executionpolicy Unrestricted

Answer (score 3):

If you're running on Windows 8 x64 then running both the commands below may help. It worked for me.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
start-job { Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force } -RunAs32
```

Credit to a comment found here:
[Powershell on Windows 7: Set-ExecutionPolicy for regular users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647429/powershell-on-windows-7-set-executionpolicy-for-regular-users)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, if after setting `powershell.exe` as your terimal in IntelliJ → Settings → Tools → Terminal → Shell path it throws `UnAuthorizedAccess` errors, normal way to solve this is to alter execution policy:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Note that `Unrestricted` level is the least secure of all, and you're usually can go with `RemoteSigned` in order to disable unsigned scripts downloaded from the web until you manually remove `Internet` or `Intranet` `Zone.Identifier` from them, usually with Unlock button in file properties.

However, you may run to an occasion when you're not able to change execution policy. Usually that's because of **corporate security settings** in Active Directory. In PowerShell, that corresponds to scopes `MachinePolicy` and `UserPolicy`. A primary symptom of this situation is the following message:

> Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy
>   successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a
>   more specific scope. Due to the override, your shell will retain its
>   current effective execution policy of AllSigned. Type
>   "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings.
>   For more information please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy".

You can't set execution policies at this scopes with PowerShell or gpedit.msc. Attempts to change this settings directly in registry is also ineffective: they're applied on restart or login, but at the same time they're being re-imported from Active Directory. However, while you won't be able to run arbitrary PowerShell scripts all around, for profiles and other local scripts that's only modified manually [there's still a solution](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/SigningPowerShellScripts.aspx):

1. Run the following command in PowerShell to create ceritificate files root.pvk and root.cer - it will ask you to define and then confirm password to the certificate:

   ```
   makecert -n "CN=PowerShell Local Certificate Root" -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -r -sv root.pvk root.cer -ss Root -sr localMachine
   ```
2. In the same folder, run the following command to import generated certificate files as your self-signed certificate - it will ask for the password you're defined above:

   ```
   makecert -pe -n "CN=PowerShell User" -ss MY -a sha1 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -iv root.pvk -ic root.cer
   ```
3. Sign your profile script with the following command:

   ```
   Set-AuthenticodeSignature "[script path]" @(Get-ChildItem cert:\CurrentUser\My -codesign)[0]
   ```
4. When running a script signed with self-ceritificate for the first time, PowerShell will ask you about trusting the certificate like this:

   > The file [script path] is published by CN=PowerShell User. This publisher is not trusted on your system. Only run scripts from trusted publishers.
   >
   > [V] Never run  [D] Do not run  [R] Run once  [A] Always run  [?] Help (default is "D")

   Answer `A` to always run self-signed certificates.

Now your profile script won't cause any errors. However, note that signing a certificate adds a signature block in the end of your script containing its hash. If you're about to modify the script, remove that block and, after you're done with editing the script, sign it again by repeating step 3.

Comment: Thanks! `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser` works great.

Answer (score 2):

Specify the shell that will run by default. Here are some examples of different shells:

Bash: /bin/bash

Z shell: /bin/zsh

Bash for Windows: bash.exe

WSL: wsl.exe

PowerShell: powershell

Command Prompt: cmd.exe

Cygwin: "C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe" --login -i

for more info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/settings-tools-terminal.html

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing (2018-9-20), there is now a PowerShell plugin available [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10249-powershell).

I have installed v1.1 in PyCharm v2018.2.3 (Professional), and it seems to work like a charm, no pun intended.

This plugin provides Intellisense-type support of PS1 scripts, as well as an integrated PowerShell terminal. In order to open the terminal, go to Tools > PowerShell Console...

There appears to be no need to muck about with any kinds of settings or permissions in order to get it to work. It Just Works.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to write `powershell` in the Shell path input, just like in the image, also you can see [jetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/terminal-emulator.html) and configure any shell you want.
[powershell configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZTR1.png)

Answer (score 0):

**For WebStorm and PowerShell 6+ on Windows 10.**
Just follow this screenshot and change the default cmd.exe to pwsh.exe from settings. Finally restart the ide. Done!

[image]