# Starting a file from within the IDE

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to start a powershell script within intellij, I have tried the powershell plugin but it doesn't allow me to open the script in a separate window. The script stops intellij and then asks me to start it again, but since intellij is closed and the script gets disconnected from it, I don't have the console window anymore and it keeps running in the background waiting for confirmation.

So my question is. How would I run a file from within intellij like when its ran it from file explorer, so it opens the file in its own window instead of the intellij console? I want it to be available in Run Configurations but I can't do it with the powershell plugin since all that the plugin does is open the script in the intellij terminal. I want to open this script in its own terminal, that is cmd.exe or powershell.exe instead of using the Terminal in IntelliJ.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949892/using-powershell-as-terminal-in-intellij-idea-ides-like-pycharm-phpstorm-or-rub

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Powershell as terminal in IntelliJ IDEA IDEs like PyCharm, PHPStorm or RubyMine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949892/using-powershell-as-terminal-in-intellij-idea-ides-like-pycharm-phpstorm-or-rub)