# Printing output strangeness in C99

Tags: c, io, c99

I have this C++ code

```
/*
Name : paintRoomCalc in C++
Author : Аїӡек Меѥҏ
Version : v1.0
License : N/A
*/

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static void getLayers(float roomWidth, float roomDepth, float roomHeight, float paintThick) {
    float edgeArea, edgeSideDepthArea, edgeSideDepthVol, edgeSideWidthArea, edgeSideWidthVol, edgeUpArea, edgeUpVol, edgeVol, roomVol, wallArea, wallFive, wallOne, wallThree, wallVol;
    double i;
    double t;
    i = 0;
    t = 0;
    roomWidth = (roomWidth * 12);
    roomDepth = (roomDepth * 12);
    roomHeight = (roomHeight * 12);
    roomVol = ((roomWidth * roomDepth) * roomHeight);
    while ((roomVol >= 0)) {
        // account for walls
        wallOne = float(roomWidth * roomHeight);
        wallThree = float(roomDepth * roomHeight);
        wallFive = float(roomDepth * roomWidth);

        wallVol = float((((wallOne * 2) + (wallThree * 2)) + wallFive) * paintThick);
        wallArea = float(((wallOne * 2) + (wallThree * 2)) + wallFive);

        roomWidth = float(roomWidth - (paintThick * 2));
        roomDepth = float(roomDepth - (paintThick * 2));
        roomHeight = float(roomHeight - (paintThick * 2));

        // account for edges going up & down
        edgeUpVol = float(roomHeight * pow(paintThick, 2));
        edgeUpVol = float(edgeUpVol * 2);
        edgeUpArea = float(roomHeight * paintThick);
        edgeUpVol = float(edgeUpArea * 2);

        // account for edges going side to side {on ceiling}
        //// account for edges going side to side {depth}
        edgeSideDepthVol = float(roomDepth * pow(paintThick, 2));
        edgeSideDepthVol = float(edgeSideDepthVol * 2);
        edgeSideDepthArea = float(roomDepth * paintThick);
        //// account for edges going side to side {width}
        edgeSideWidthVol = float(roomWidth * pow(paintThick, 2));
        edgeSideWidthVol = float(edgeSideWidthVol * 2);
        edgeSideWidthArea = float(roomWidth * paintThick);
        edgeVol = float((edgeUpVol + edgeSideWidthVol) + edgeSideDepthVol);

        // add edges
        edgeArea = float((edgeUpArea + edgeSideWidthArea) + edgeSideDepthArea);

        // calculate final values
        roomVol = float((roomVol - wallVol) - edgeVol);
        wallArea = float(wallArea - edgeArea);

        i += 1;
        t += wallArea;
    }
    cout << i << " layers to fill your room with paint!!" << endl;
    cout << "& " << t / 4800 << " gallons of paint" << endl;
}
int main() {
    float roomWidth, roomDepth, roomHeight, paintThickMil;
    float paintThick;
    cout << "Paint Layer Calculator" << endl;
    cout << "by : izder456" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    //get input for room dimentions
    cout << "Room Width in Feet? ";
    cin >> roomWidth;
    cout << "Room Depth in Feet? ";
    cin >> roomDepth;
    cout << "Room Height in Feet? ";
    cin >> roomHeight;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "1 mil is 1/1000 of an inch" << endl;
    cout << "Paint Thickness in Mils? ";
    cin >> paintThickMil;
    paintThick = paintThickMil / 1000;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Calculating..." << endl;

    getLayers(roomWidth, roomDepth, roomHeight, paintThick);
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

that i converted to C :

```
/*
Name : paintRoomCalc in C
Author : Аїӡек Меѥҏ
Version : b0.1
License : N/A
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void getLayers(float roomWidth, float roomDepth, float roomHeight, float paintThick) {
    float edgeArea, edgeSideDepthArea, edgeSideDepthVol, edgeSideWidthArea, edgeSideWidthVol, edgeUpArea, edgeUpVol, edgeVol, roomVol, wallArea, wallFive, wallOne, wallThree, wallVol;
    double i;
    double t;
    i = 0;
    t = 0;
    roomWidth = (roomWidth * 12);
    roomDepth = (roomDepth * 12);
    roomHeight = (roomHeight * 12);
    roomVol = ((roomWidth * roomDepth) * roomHeight);
    while (roomVol >= 0) {
        // account for walls
        wallOne = (float)(roomWidth * roomHeight);
        wallThree = (float)(roomDepth * roomHeight);
        wallFive = (float)(roomDepth * roomWidth);

        wallVol = (float)((((wallOne * 2) + (wallThree * 2)) + wallFive) * paintThick);
        wallArea = (float)(((wallOne * 2) + (wallThree * 2)) + wallFive);

        roomWidth = (float)(roomWidth - (paintThick * 2));
        roomDepth = (float)(roomDepth - (paintThick * 2));
        roomHeight = (float)(roomHeight - (paintThick * 2));

        // account for edges going up & down
        edgeUpVol = (float)(roomHeight * pow(paintThick, 2));
        edgeUpVol = (float)(edgeUpVol * 2);
        edgeUpArea = (float)(roomHeight * paintThick);
        edgeUpVol = (float)(edgeUpArea * 2);

        // account for edges going side to side {on ceiling}
        //// account for edges going side to side {depth}
        edgeSideDepthVol = (float)(roomDepth * pow(paintThick, 2));
        edgeSideDepthVol = (float)(edgeSideDepthVol * 2);
        edgeSideDepthArea = (float)(roomDepth * paintThick);
        //// account for edges going side to side {width}
        edgeSideWidthVol = (float)(roomWidth * pow(paintThick, 2));
        edgeSideWidthVol = (float)(edgeSideWidthVol * 2);
        edgeSideWidthArea = (float)(roomWidth * paintThick);
        edgeVol = (float)((edgeUpVol + edgeSideWidthVol) + edgeSideDepthVol);

        // add edges
        edgeArea = (float)((edgeUpArea + edgeSideWidthArea) + edgeSideDepthArea);

        // calculate final values
        roomVol = (float)((roomVol - wallVol) - edgeVol);
        wallArea = (float)(wallArea - edgeArea);

        i += 1;
        t += wallArea;
    }
    printf("%f layers to fill your room with paint!!\n",i);
    printf("& %f gallons of paint",((float)t/(float)4800));
};

int main() {
    float roomWidth, roomDepth, roomHeight, paintThickMil;
    float paintThick;
    printf("Paint Layer Calculator\n");
    printf("by : izder456\n");
    printf("\n");

    //get input for room dimentions
    printf("Room Width in Feet? ");
    scanf("%f", &roomWidth);
    printf("Room Depth in Feet? ");
    scanf("%f", &roomDepth);
    printf("Room Height in Feet? ");
    scanf("%f", &roomHeight);
    printf("1 mil is 1/1000 of an inch\n");
    printf("Paint Thickness in Mils? ");
    scanf("%f", &paintThickMil);
    paintThick = ((float)(paintThickMil))/((float)(1000));
    printf("\n");
    printf("Calculating...\n");

    getLayers(roomWidth, roomDepth, roomHeight, paintThick);
    while(getchar() != '\n');

    return 0;
}
```

when compiling and running with the C99 standard in the CLion IDE, I get weird output; like this :

```
Paint Layer Calculator
by : izder456

Room Width in Feet?1
 Room Depth in Feet?2
 Room Height in Feet?3
 1 mil is 1/1000 of an inch
Paint Thickness in Mils?2

Calculating...
3332.000000 layers to fill your room with paint!!
& 1039.159058 gallons of paint
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want it to look like this :

```
Paint Layer Calculator
by : izder456

Room Width in Feet? 1
Room Depth in Feet? 2
Room Height in Feet? 3

1 mil is 1/1000 of an inch
Paint Thickness in Mils? 2

Calculating...
3332.000000 layers to fill your room with paint!!
& 1039.159058 gallons of paint
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I want the spaces to be in between the prompts and the input; I don't want them at the beginning of the line like it does. I also want there to be a spacer in between the second-to-final question and the line before the final question, like in the C++ version.

how would I format the `scanf` and `printf` in `main()` to get this format of i/o?

your help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the white space shows up perfectly fine.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727656/white-space-on-the-end-of-output-string-not-printing-with-the-string-but-rather)

Comment: seems to be an issue with CLion IDE & buffers. I'll just use a different IDE...