# Powershell 1.0 Set-Execution for LOCAL SYSTEM account

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2003

On a windows 2003 Server, I have a Powershell 1.0 script that I can execute happily as myself due to setting the Execution Policy to `remoteSigned` in my own user.

Upgrading to current/newer technology is out of the question I'm afraid.

The script needs to actually be called from a Windows Service that is running under the `LOCALSYSTEM` account.

I suspect that the Execution Policy for this account is still restricting access to run the scripts.

Is there a way of setting the Execution Policy for the SYSTEM account to enable the scripts to run?

Perhaps a system wide setting??

Comment: Can you do a `Get-ExecutionPolicy -list` and post the output as part of your question?

Comment: All working now. It was a PATH setting to Powershell.exe not being picked up by the LOCAL SYSTEM account. code rectified to include full path and everything works - Feeling very sheepish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4647585/140377 you can just run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` as an administrator and it will apply to all users.

Comment: It doesn't like the -Scope switch. It isn't supported at Powershell 1.0

Comment: If I told you all that the SYSTEM account doesn't look at the PATH in the environment variables and I'd overlooked this... would you all shout at me? 

I have now added the full path to Powershell.exe in the call and things are working. I've up-voted all answers at time of writing because even though they didn't solve it, they proved that I wasn't losing ALL of my marbles.

Comment: @thonnor No worries. We've all been there.