# Enable/disable ClearType without logging out

Tags: windows-7, command-line, registry, cleartype

I need to enable/disable ClearType (or "Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows > Smooth edges of screen fonts") via `cmd` (or any script like VBS/JS) or from the registry *without* logging out or restarting Windows.

Maybe it's possible to enable ClearType only for one application.

Answer (score 16):

The modern way of scripting under Windows is using PowerShell. The following script requires version 2.0, which is available from Windows XP SP3:

```cs
#requires -version 2.0
param([bool]$enable)

$signature = @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
    uint uiAction,
    uint uiParam,
    uint pvParam,
    uint fWinIni);
'@

$SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING      = 0x004B
$SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE  = 0x200B
$SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE        = 0x1
$SPIF_SENDCHANGE           = 0x2
$FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE = 0x2

$winapi = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name WinAPI -PassThru

if ($enable)
{
    [void]$winapi::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 1, 0, $SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE -bor $SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
    [void]$winapi::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE, 0, $FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE, $SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE -bor $SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
}
else
{
    [void]$winapi::SystemParametersInfo($SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, 0, $SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE -bor $SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
}
```

If, for some reason, you can't use PowerShell, you'll need [DynamicWrapperX](http://www.script-coding.com/dynwrapx_eng.html) in order to execute WinAPI functions in WSH. You will first need to register it on the target machine, then you could use this VBScript:

```vb
Set WinAPI = CreateObject("DynamicWrapperX")
WinAPI.Register "user32.dll", "SystemParametersInfo", "i=uuuu"

Const SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING      = &H004B
Const SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE  = &H200B
Const SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE        = &H1
Const SPIF_SENDCHANGE           = &H2
Const FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE = &H2

If WScript.Arguments(0) Then
    WinAPI.SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 1, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDCHANGE
    WinAPI.SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE, 0, FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDCHANGE
Else
    WinAPI.SystemParametersInfo SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, 0, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDCHANGE
End If
```

Both scripts accept one parameter, `0` means disable ClearType, `1` means enable. No reboot is needed.

Comment: Do I copy this and just insert and press enter or do I need to save it to some powershell executable script text file and double-click?

Comment: @user1306322, you copy the script and save it as `.ps1` file. Then you can run it like `powershell "& 'C:\myscript.ps1' 1"` from the command line. It is possible to tweak the system registry so you can double-click the file, though.

Comment: Okay, now I get `File C:\asd.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system.` error, which seems to be common. I guess I'll have to go with one of first google results to fix this.

Comment: @user1306322, `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` should allow running all scripts, but `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` is probably more secure. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but the command line to disable all font smoothing is `powershell "& 'C:\myscript.ps1' 0"`.

Comment: @user1306322, yes, exactly. Like I wrote in the answer: `Both scripts accept one parameter, 0 means disable ClearType, 1 means enable.`

Comment: I can't believe this hasn't gotten more upvotes. This rocks! I love the use of dynamically added types in PowerShell, too

Answer (score 7):

Just to add more options, I have the C# version, adding GetFontSmoothing to it.

```cs
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, ref int pvParam, uint fWinIni);

    const uint SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING = 74;
    const uint SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING = 75;
    const uint SPI_UPDATEINI = 0x1;
    const UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x1;

    private Boolean GetFontSmoothing()
    {
        bool iResult;
        int pv = 0;
        /* Call to systemparametersinfo to get the font smoothing value. */
        iResult = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, ref pv, 0);
        if (pv > 0)
        {
            //pv > 0 means font smoothing is on.
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //pv == 0 means font smoothing is off.
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void DisableFontSmoothing()
    {
        bool iResult;
        int pv = 0;
        /* Call to systemparametersinfo to set the font smoothing value. */
        iResult = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 0, ref pv, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        Console.WriteLine("Disabled: {0}", iResult);
    }

    private void EnableFontSmoothing()
    {
        bool iResult;
        int pv = 0;
        /* Call to systemparametersinfo to set the font smoothing value. */
        iResult = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, 1, ref pv, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);
        Console.WriteLine("Enabled: {0}", iResult);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Carol. We've implemented a client application which works more than 3k machines and I will be using your solution which works completely perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Python version:

```
# make sure you install pywin32 
# from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/
import win32con
import win32gui

win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHING, True, 0) # enable only
win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETFONTSMOOTHINGTYPE,
        win32con.FE_FONTSMOOTHINGCLEARTYPE,
        win32con.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | win32con.SPIF_SENDCHANGE)
```

Answer (score 2):

make file with extention .`reg` this is registry for files

Disable_Smooth_edges_of_screen_fonts

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="0"
```

Enable_Smooth_edges_of_screen_fonts

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="2"
```

you can also do this vis cmd 
here is syntax for  command

```
REG ADD KeyName [/v ValueName | /ve] [/t Type] [/s Separator] [/d Data] [/f]
```

you must logoff to have effect that you changed

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how to do it without Rebooting...

But i found that changing the FontSmoothing keys was simply not enough...

For a full procedure on how to completely remove ClearType and FontSmoothing, check this out:

[Completley Disable Font Smoothing and ClearType in Windows 7](http://hellspawndev.blogspot.com/2011/06/completley-disbable-font-smoothing-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me:
Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced > (Performance) Settings > Visual Effects > Select 'Custom' and uncheck 'Smooth edges of screen fonts'

Answer (score 1):

Look at the stuff described in the following link:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=491091

Calling the API might trigger the system-wide update so you do not have to logoff/logon to see the change.

Of course, this is not limited to vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PowerShell way to do it:

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop\' -Name FontSmoothing -Value "2"
```

You'll need to log off and back on for it to take effect.

> NOTE: strangely the setting doesn't show up as enabled in Performance
>   Options, even though it's clearly turned on:

[image]