# How to Enable font cleartype in windows with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, windows, webfonts, cleartype

I am using a client font(Custom web fonts) in a webpage which requires a small setting in controlpanel to be done. We have to select the font clear type in control panel. (As shown in the pic). Otherwise the font comes up with uneven edges.

Other than manual selection is there any way to achieve this configurtion.

Is there any way we can make this adjustment in the html, css or js only?

Below are the font-faces i am using

```
@font-face {
     font-family:'BTFont_Rg';
     src: url('../fonts/BTFont_Rg.eot');
     src: local('☺'), url('../fonts/BTFont_Rg.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/BTFont_Rg.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/BTFont_Rg.svg') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

We are using Xampp.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked the Inspector to see if there are any loading errors?

Comment: I've seen these types of errors when the optimal font type is not loading and another is allowed to load.  Generally, the font types need to be registered in the server settings.

Comment: Nope , No errors. Its basically Windows configuration.

Comment: Check out older questions on ClearType, especially http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676768/enable-disable-cleartype-in-windows7

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, But how i can do it with plain javascript. Is there any way to achieve with Plain java script. Its basic HTML CSS application right now.

Comment: Try something like font squirrel's generator.  http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator ... this will even provide solid CSS for usage in HTML.