# How to run cmd command in Python with admin

Tags: python, windows-7

I want to run a windows command with Python 3. Like this os.system("echo hi"). However, How about running a command that requires admin access? How do you do this? Thanks.

Comment: Use `runas`. See, e.g., [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415653/run-batch-file-as-administrator-windows-7-command-run-as-from-network-file) and, if entering a password on the shell is not an option, [this](https://superuser.com/questions/55809/how-to-run-program-from-command-line-with-elevated-rights)

Comment: It's a builtin Windows program that allows you to execute other programs as other users, provided you know their password. See e.g. the first link in my comment.

Comment: The problem is that this program is going to be distributed, and it obviously can't know the passwords.

Comment: can you not get the user to enter the password?

Comment: I suppose so. What would the code for runas look like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this with the ShellExecuteEx Win32 API wrapper included in the [Pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) extensions. If you are using something like ActivePython you may already have the extensions.

To use ShellExecuteEx :

```
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
commands = 'echo hi'
shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile='cmd.exe', lpParameters='/c '+commands)
```

Comment: Excellent! Can we do this without the pop-up window?

Comment: Do you mean the [User Account Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) pop-up? You're not really supposed to disable that. There are ways around it listed in [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/200788/how-to-run-an-app-as-administrator-without-the-prompt) but they all are a bit awkward.

Comment: Oh. It's really annoying, though!\

Comment: What if we had the user's password?

Comment: Just going to close the question, and start another. Thanks!

Comment: @LukeDinkler One way for stopping popup : Run your python as admin then execute the scripts. Then automatically all the scripts would have the admin access, and they will not show popups.

Comment: Running this in a python file I dont see the echo :(

Comment: This appears to be deprecated in Python 3 and I'm having trouble finding the analogous Python 3 approach.