# how to run the admin command prompt using python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to run a script on the admin cmd prompt using python os.system

```
import os
import sys
import keyboard
import time

os.system('cls')
print('+'* 60)
os.system('netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=test3 key=987654321')
time.sleep(2)
p = input('')
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
print('@' * 60)
os.system('netsh wlan start hostednetwork')
time.sleep(2)
keyboard.press_and_release('enter')
v = input('')
```

How can I call the admin cmd prompt ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run cmd command in Python with admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557921/how-to-run-cmd-command-in-python-with-admin)

Comment: first of all thank you for your suggestion, but the code out there works only  to popup admin window, it doesn't execute the given command
I've tried 

import win32com.shell.shell as shell
commands = 'ipconfig'
shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile='cmd.exe', lpParameters='/c '+commands)

Comment: didn't find a thing through your shared question, check out my answer here, I solve the problem using batch file.. and thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make this happen
so my idea is to to create script to share wifi using python, and the problem is you have to execute the script using admin command prompt. and to solve that, follow my steps:

1 - create the python script for the commands(copy mine in the original question)
2 - create a simple text file like this one

```
pause 
python name.py
pause
```

3 - save it under the extension of " .bat " (example.bat)
4 - go to your system directory (mine is "C:\Windows\System32")
5 - copy the the batch file there
6 - create a shortcut for this batch file (it will ask to be in your desktop, click OK)
7 - go to the properties of this shortcuted file click on advanced and give it the admin 
    access - click OK
8- copy or cut your script.py file to the same directory (mine is "C:\Windows\System32")

and that's it, just launch your batch file in the desktop and here you go everything works fine.