# How can I run cmd command to renew Kerberos ticket in python

Tags: python, cmd, kerberos, renewal

Dears,
I used to renew kerberos ticket using CMD Command as following:
C:\program files (x86)\MIT\kerberos\bin>kinit
as below ..

[image]

then when i put the password , tkt gets renewed ..

so, how I can run same cmd commands in Python??!!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command you use inside:

```
import os
os.system("YOUR COMMAND")
```

Comment: Note: this will only work for commands that do not require admin acces

Comment: See "https://stackoverflow.com/a/25558966/13896565" if you want to run commands that require admin access

Comment: Tip: implement your comments with your answer. Comment is for reply to one others comment. It als increases your answers value and may help accelerate up-voting.