# Not able to start novnc on Windows 2008 @ port 80

Tags: websocket

I have started noVnc on windows using port 6080 and its working fine. Now I would like to start on port 80 and but script shows error on start.

"socket.error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted"

I tried the following command: utils/launch.sh --listen 80 --vnc localhost:5900

Please let me know how can I fix it, I don't have any IIS installed on windows 2008 R2 machine.

Thanks,
Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports less than 1024 are considered privileged so you must have administrative privilege when you run something that wants to use them.

See this answer about using runas.exe: [How to run an application as "run as administrator" from the command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-app-as-run-as-administrator-from-command-prompt)