# Running Eleveted Command Prompt without admin username and password

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

Using the command (or another command/module) `subprocess.call(['filepath.exe'])`, can you run an elevated command prompt without having to input an admin username and password?

(Windows 7 - assuming I cannot access command prompt through run or the start menu)

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-app-as-run-as-administrator-from-command-prompt

Comment: Run the script as administrator. Otherwise, no. If programs could run something else as elevated, without asking the user, that would defeat the whole purpose of UAC.