# WinSCP log not generating

Tags: batch-file, winscp

I am using WinSCP for file transfer to a remote instance.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>WinSCP.com sftp://root@<some IP>/ /log="C:
\winscp.log"

put D:\backup\hello.txt ./test1/
```

It is logging in perfectly and also the file is transferring, but it is not generating any log for that on the local path I have specified. How to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If there's any problem with logging, WinSCP would issue an error message on its output. It would help if you show us the output.*

Anyway, I guess the problem is that one generally does not have a write access to `C:\` root folder. Of course, unless you run WinSCP as an administrator.

Comment: ya, i tried it the way u suggested, it work good with that, but how do i run winscp from command line as an administrator ?

Comment: Well, that's for a different question. Or actually, it's answered already: [How to run an app as “run as administrator” from command prompt?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8249705/850848)