# dart compilation for windows not work for every version? is there are any work arounds?

Tags: windows, dart, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016, flutter-windows

so recently I have created a program in `dart` and compiled that program to `exe` file on my `windows10` machine. Using `dart compile exe main.dart` and then `main.exe` is generated, but the problem is when I try to run this script on different version of windows like `windows 11`, `windows server 2016` or `windows server 2012`. It didn't seem to run the program.

[image: program error on Windows server 2012]

Note that actually there is no folder missing, still it is giving `FileSystemException` but only for `windows server 2012`, `windows 11`, and `windows server 2016` not for `windows 10`.

I am only saying is that why is this error not occurred in `windows 10` my guess is because I created the binary in `windows 10`.

I have searched about this but couldn't find a way is there is any way I can compile this binary, so it works in all version of windows? Or like `dart compile exe --windows11` for `windows 11`.

**Does dart only compile for Windows version specific binary, not for general `win32` APIs?**

Comment: I suspect you're running into a permissions issue, rather than a compilation issue - Are you sure the other accounts have administrative access (to access C:\Users\Administrator)? What happens if you [run as administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249705/how-to-run-an-application-as-run-as-administrator-from-the-command-prompt) on the other systems?

Comment: Also, what happens if you run the script without AOT compilation on the other systems?

Comment: @MichaelHorn yes it could be thanks for your comment, Yes I have run AOT compilation on Linux it runs perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelHorn It is not issue of permissions since I tried running using Administrator access as well but got the same error.