# How to export/import PuTTY sessions list?

Tags: windows, registry, putty

Is there a way to do this?

Or I have to take manually every record from Registry?

Answer (score 1540, accepted):

## Export

### `cmd.exe`, *requires* elevated prompt due to regedit:

Only sessions (produces file `putty-sessions.reg` on the Desktop):

```
regedit /e "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\putty-sessions.reg" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions
```

All settings except ssh keys (produces file `putty.reg` on the Desktop):

```
regedit /e "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\putty.reg" HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham
```

---

### Powershell:

Only sessions (produces file `putty-sessions.reg` on the Desktop):

```
reg export HKCU\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\putty-sessions.reg")
```

All settings except ssh keys (produces file `putty.reg` on the Desktop):

```
reg export HKCU\Software\SimonTatham ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop") + "\putty.reg")
```

---

## Import

Double-click on the `*.reg` file and accept the import.

### Alternative ways:

#### `cmd.exe`, *requires* elevated command prompt:

```
regedit /i putty-sessions.reg
regedit /i putty.reg
```

#### PowerShell:

```
reg import putty-sessions.reg
reg import putty.reg
```

---

*Note*: **do not replace** `SimonTatham` with your username.

*Note*: These commands will **not** export the related SSH keys.

Comment: I got the error as snapshot here - how to get over it? https://www.dropbox.com/s/om426f8gen9mhxs/how-to-export-putty-sessions-list.png?dl=0

Comment: @NamGVU That's because path have a folder with spaces. Move to one that didn't have it.

Comment: I tried with no space in export path and the error remains though.

Comment: @NamGVU Do not replace %userprofile% with your username, leave it as is.

Comment: Second Command worked for me on Windows 7, however, I needed to run CMD as administrator.

Comment: Ran the 1st command from Run rather than cmd and got file 'putty-sessions.reg' on desktop (Win7).

Comment: I was inspired by your answer to help sleske : http://serverfault.com/a/745968/329412

Comment: I'm getting nothing on Windows 10

Comment: @mparnisari Check your Desktop. It should create a `.reg` file there with all the settings.

Comment: This worked for me moving this from Windows 7 to Windows 10, but I had to run regedit as myself and use the Import feature there. Otherwise, just trying to import the .reg file itself on the new computer imported the settings to the Administrative user instead.

Comment: I tried this and did not get any file. I searched the registry and there was no key named 'SimonTatham'. This is with putty version 0.62 with Windows 7.

Comment: To import, I opened the pc where I wanted to import the putty info. windows start button->run regedit->File->Import and import the each .reg file respectively.

Comment: This does not seem to work the way that I expected.  My group works with around 50 hosts which I have saved sessions for in Pageant/PuTTy.  The export method above creates a file, but when I look at it using Edit, I do not see any of host names or addresses.  Just options stuff like color, terminal type, etc.  Am I missing something or misunderstanding what this is suppose to do?  Thanks.

Comment: @ScottLaw The first command will export only the sessions, still they will have other options, like color, fonts etc. Try searching `HostName`, for example.

Comment: @m0nhawk: No, it just wasn't there.  Looking at the GUI version, I suddenly woke up to the fact that both the folders under sessions were from an older project that I was on, neither of which were in my current saved sessions.  I did a search for one of my current hostnames through the whole registry and found a pile in HKEY_USERS in some Microsoft package and it contained basically every one that I have ever saved included my current stack.  Right click and save that sessions folder and I think I am good now.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Though if you go this route and are trying to provide a resource for new users, I would suggest editing the exported file to replace all occurrences of the path (mine was buried way down in HKEY_USERS) with HKEY_CURRENT_USER.  Also also have the new user replace all your username references with their own before importing.

Comment: export worked to one computer but not in another (couldn't find the reg file), why? Both were similar with same OS (Win10)

Comment: As far as I know you don't need elevated command prompt when you export from branch `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\...`. Elevated rights are required only for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, etc.

Comment: If it is PuTTy 64, it is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY64`.

Comment: Some putty installs on Windows (and every install on Linux) do not use the registry, mind how you go.

Comment: So oldschool, incredible

Comment: For me the settings were store in: [HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-{huge long ID number}\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY] Inserting the data into the regular places above didnt work. It took a lot of searching through the registry to find this. If they're going to be stored in such a silly place, Putty really should just add an export function.

Comment: Should not need elevated right. If your 'Admin' user is different from the current user (which Putty is installed with), HKEY_CURRENT_USER would reference to that 'Admin' user rather than the current 'regular' user. And you will either export sessions of that 'admin' user, or not finding the correct registry entries at all.

Comment: @Quickpick No, elevated is not required, at least not on Windows 10+ when I tried it.

Comment: As a note, it's not possible to import a registry file that is located on a network drive. You need to copy it to the computer then import it.

Answer (score 80):

1. Launch Run, then type `regedit` in the open drop down window
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham`
3. Right click on 'SimonTatham' key (directory icon), select Export. Give the file a name (say) `putty.reg` and save it to your location for later use.
4. Close Registry Editor.

Done.

Comment: After export, copy that .reg file to the computer that you want to use those setting.
Simply double click it to take effect.

Answer (score 66):

When I tried the other solutions I got this error:

```
Registry editing has been disabled by your administrator.
```

Phooey to that, I say!

I put together the below powershell scripts for exporting and importing PuTTY settings. The exported file is a windows .reg file and will import cleanly if you have permission, otherwise use import.ps1 to load it.

**Warning**: messing with the registry like this is a Bad Idea™, and I don't really know what I'm doing. Use the  below scripts at your own risk, and be prepared to have your IT department re-image your machine and ask you uncomfortable questions about what you were doing.

On the source machine:

```
.\export.ps1
```

On the target machine:

```
.\import.ps1 > cmd.ps1
# Examine cmd.ps1 to ensure it doesn't do anything nasty
.\cmd.ps1
```

export.ps1

```cs
# All settings
$registry_path = "HKCU:\Software\SimonTatham"
# Only sessions
#$registry_path = "HKCU:\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions"
$output_file = "putty.reg"

$registry = ls "$registry_path" -Recurse

"Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00" | Out-File putty.reg
"" | Out-File putty.reg -Append

foreach ($reg in $registry) {
  "[$reg]" | Out-File putty.reg -Append
  foreach ($prop in $reg.property) {
    $propval = $reg.GetValue($prop)
    if ("".GetType().Equals($propval.GetType())) {
      '"' + "$prop" + '"' + "=" + '"' + "$propval" + '"' | Out-File putty.reg -Append
    } elseif ($propval -is [int]) {
      $hex = "{0:x8}" -f $propval
      '"' + "$prop" + '"' + "=dword:" + $hex | Out-File putty.reg -Append
    }
  }
  "" | Out-File putty.reg -Append
}
```

import.ps1

```cs
$input_file = "putty.reg"

$content = Get-Content "$input_file"

"Push-Location"
"cd HKCU:\"

foreach ($line in $content) { 
  If ($line.StartsWith("Windows Registry Editor")) {
    # Ignore the header
  } ElseIf ($line.startswith("[")) {
    $section = $line.Trim().Trim('[', ']')
    'New-Item -Path "' + $section + '" -Force' | %{ $_ -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\', '' }
  } ElseIf ($line.startswith('"')) {
    $linesplit = $line.split('=', 2)
    $key = $linesplit[0].Trim('"')
    if ($linesplit[1].StartsWith('"')) {
      $value = $linesplit[1].Trim().Trim('"')
    } ElseIf ($linesplit[1].StartsWith('dword:')) {
      $value = [Int32]('0x' + $linesplit[1].Trim().Split(':', 2)[1])
      'New-ItemProperty "' + $section + '" "' + $key + '" -PropertyType dword -Force' | %{ $_ -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\', '' }
    } Else {
      Write-Host "Error: unknown property type: $linesplit[1]"
      exit
    }
    'Set-ItemProperty -Path "' + $section + '" -Name "' + $key + '" -Value "' + $value + '"' | %{ $_ -replace 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\', '' }
  }
}

"Pop-Location"
```

Apologies for the non-idiomatic code, I'm not very familiar with Powershell. Improvements are welcome!

Comment: Worked perfectly, what a time-saver.  One addition ... I had to follow instructions here to setup permissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system.

Comment: That was a great help! I had different registry locations just had to edit the path in both and that was it :)

Comment: Wait, so PowerShell circumvents group policy? Wonder how long until _that_ gets patched.

Comment: Not sure, but we're at four years and counting ;)

Comment: This bug, fortunately, does not seem to be present in Windows 10 1909. Using New-Item as a regular user on the Registry PSProvider now throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: PuTTY is a program that can edit your registry. If they "patch" your permissions so user-runnable programs can't edit the registry you won't have any PuTTY settings to export.

Comment: The import script did not work for me, but I was able to just open regedit and import the exported file.

Answer (score 39):

If You want to import settings on `PuTTY Portable` You can use the  `putty.reg` file.

Just put it to this path `[path_to_Your_portable_apps]PuTTYPortable\Data\settings\putty.reg`. Program will import it

Answer (score 27):

For those of you who need to import Putty from offline registry file e.g. when you are recovering from crashed system or simply moving to a new machine and grabbing data off that old drive there is one more solution worth mentioning:

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_file_offline_export.html

This great and free console application will export the entire registry or only a specific registry key. In my case i simply copied the registry file from an old drive to the same directory as the exporter tool and then i used following command and syntax in CMD window run as administrator:

RegFileExport.exe NTUSER.DAT putty.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham"

After importing the .reg file and starting Putty everything was there. Simple and efficient.

Comment: I would add a note that the NTUSER.DAT is located in Users/[Username] as a protected system file, and not in Windows/SYSTEM32/Config.

Answer (score 18):

For those who don't want to mess with the registry, a variation of putty that saves to file has been created. It is located here: http://jakub.kotrla.net/putty/

It would be nice if the putty team would take this as an option into the main distribution.

Answer (score 16):

m0nhawk's answer didn't work for me on Windows 10 - it required elevated command prompt and refused to emit a file.

This worked and didn't require elevation:

```
reg export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY putty.reg
```

Answer (score 14):

This was so much easier importing the registry export than what is stated above.
+
Simply:

1. right click on the file and
2. select "Merge"

Worked like a champ on Win 7 Pro.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows 10 also

Comment: I can confirm - it works flawlessly on Win10. Easiest "import" ever. Thanks!

Comment: What file where?

Answer (score 14):

**Example:**
How to transfer putty configuration and session configuration from one user account to another e.g. when created a new account and want to use the putty sessions/configurations from the old account

**Process:**
 - Export registry key from old account into a file
 - Import registry key from file into new account

**Export reg key:** *(from OLD account)*

1. Login into the OLD account e.g. tomold
2. Open normal  'command prompt' (NOT admin !)
3. Type 'regedit'
4. Navigate to registry section where the configuration is being stored e.g. [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham] and click on it
5. Select 'Export' from the file menu or right mouse click (radio ctrl 'selected branch')
6. Save into file and name it e.g. 'puttyconfig.reg'
7. Logout again

**Import reg key:** *(into NEW account)*

8. Login into NEW account e.g. tom
9. Open normal 'command prompt' (NOT admin !)
10. Type 'regedit'
11. Select 'Import' from the menu
12. Select the registry file to import e.g. 'puttyconfig.reg'
13. Done

**Note:**
Do not use an 'admin command prompt' as settings are located under '[HKEY_CURRENT_USER...] 'and regedit would run as admin and show that section for the admin-user rather then for the user to transfer from and/or to.

Answer (score 13):

If you, like me, installed new Windows and only **after** you remember about putty sessions, you can still import them, if you have old Windows hard drive or at least your old "home" directory backed up (`C:\Users\<user_name>`).

In this directory there should be `NTUSER.DAT` file. It is hidden by default, so you should enable hidden files in your Windows explorer or use another file browser. This file contains the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` branch of your old Windows registry.

To use it, you need to open `regedit` on your new Windows, and select `HKEY_USERS` key.

Then select `File` -> `Load Hive...` and find your old "home" directory of your old Windows installation. In this directory there should be `NTUSER.DAT` file. It is hidden by default, so, if you didn't enable to show hidden files in your Windows explorer properties, then you can just manually enter file name into `File name` input box of "Load Hive" dialog and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then in the next dialog window enter some key name to load old registry into it. e.g. `tmp`.

Your old registry's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` branch now should be accessible under `HKEY_USERS\tmp` branch of your current registry.

Now export `HKEY_USERS\tmp\Software\SimonTatham` branch into `putty.reg` file, open this file in your favorite text editor and find-and-replace all `HKEY_USERS\tmp` string with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Now save the `.reg` file.

You can import now this file into your current Windows registry by double-clicking it. See [m0nhawk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13023979/758991) how to do this.

In the end, select `HKEY_USERS\tmp` branch in the registry editor and then select `File` -> `Unload Hive...` and confirm this operation.

Comment: This answer along with https://superuser.com/a/1370670/1198855 helped me to solve the problem. I had an error while loading the hive for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

An improvement to the solution of bumerang to import data to `PuTTY portable`.

Simply moving exported `putty.reg` (with m0nhawk solution) to `PuTTYPortable\Data\settings\` didn't work. PuTTY Portable backup the file and create a new empty one.

To workaround this issue, merge both `putty.reg` copying manually the config you want to migrate from your exported `putty.reg` to the newly created `PuTTYPortable\Data\settings\putty.reg` below following lines.

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY]
"RandSeedFile"="D:\\Programme\\PuTTYPortable\\Data\\settings\\PUTTY.RND"
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer posted by @m0nhawk doesn't seem to work as I test on a Windows 7 machine.
Instead, using the following scripts would export/import the settings of putty:

```
::export
@echo off
set regfile=putty.reg
pushd %~dp0

reg export HKCU\Software\SimonTatham %regfile% /y

popd
```

--

```
::import
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
set regfile=putty.reg

if exist %regfile% reg import %regfile%

popd
```

Answer (score 6):

Using this method it is also possible to perform mass configuration changes, such as changing the all sessions font.

1. Export to .reg
2. Perform a search and replace over .reg
3. Remove all sessions
4. Import the new .reg

Extracted from here: http://www.sysadmit.com/2015/11/putty-exportar-configuracion.html

Answer (score 4):

There is a PowerShell script at [ratil.life/first-useful-powershell-script-putty-to-ssh-config](https://ratil.life/first-useful-powershell-script-putty-to-ssh-config/) which can convert the sessions to a format that can be used in `.ssh/config`.  It can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/tmsteen/PowerShell-Scripts/blob/master/PuTTY_to_SSH_config.ps1).

This excerpt contains the main guts of the code, and will print the resulting config directly to stdout:

```
# Registry path to PuTTY configured profiles
$regPath = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions'

# Iterate over each PuTTY profile
Get-ChildItem $regPath -Name | ForEach-Object {

    # Check if SSH config
    if (((Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath\$_").Protocol) -eq 'ssh') {
        # Write the Host for easy SSH use
        $host_nospace = $_.replace('%20', $SpaceChar)
        $hostLine =  "Host $host_nospace"

        # Parse Hostname for special use cases (Bastion) to create SSH hostname
        $puttyHostname = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath\$_").HostName
        if ($puttyHostname -like '*@*') {
            $sshHostname = $puttyHostname.split("@")[-1]
            }
        else { $sshHostname = $puttyHostname }
        $hostnameLine = "`tHostName $sshHostname"   

        # Parse Hostname for special cases (Bastion) to create User
        if ($puttyHostname -like '*@*') {
            $sshUser = $puttyHostname.split("@")[0..($puttyHostname.split('@').length - 2)] -join '@'
            }
        else { $sshHostname = $puttyHostname }
        $userLine = "`tUser $sshUser"   

        # Parse for Identity File
        $puttyKeyfile = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath\$_").PublicKeyFile
        if ($puttyKeyfile) { 
            $sshKeyfile = $puttyKeyfile.replace('\', '/')
            if ($prefix) { $sshKeyfile = $sshKeyfile.replace('C:', $prefix) }
            $identityLine = "`tIdentityFile $sshKeyfile"
            }

        # Parse Configured Tunnels
        $puttyTunnels = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath\$_").PortForwardings
        if ($puttyTunnels) {
            $puttyTunnels.split() | ForEach-Object {

                # First character denotes tunnel type
                $tunnelType = $_.Substring(0,1)
                # Digits follow tunnel type is local port
                $tunnelPort = $_ -match '\d*\d(?==)' | Foreach {$Matches[0]}
                # Text after '=' is the tunnel destination
                $tunnelDest = $_.split('=')[1]

                if ($tunnelType -eq 'D') {
                    $tunnelLine = "`tDynamicForward $tunnelPort $tunnelDest"
                }

                ElseIf ($tunnelType -eq 'R') {
                    $tunnelLine = "`tRemoteForward $tunnelPort $tunnelDest"
                }

                ElseIf ($tunnelType -eq 'L') {
                    $tunnelLine = "`tLocalForward $tunnelPort $tunnelDest"
                }

            }

        # Parse if Forward Agent is required
        $puttyAgent = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath\$_").AgentFwd
        if ($puttyAgent -eq 1) { $agentLine = "`tForwardAgent yes" }

        # Parse if non-default port
        $puttyPort = (Get-ItemProperty -Path "$regPath\$_").PortNumber
        if (-Not $puttyPort -eq 22) { $PortLine = "`tPort $puttyPort" }

        }

        # Build output string
        $output = "$hostLine`n$hostnameLine`n$userLine`n$identityLine`n$tunnelLine`n$agentLine`n"

        # Output to file if set, otherwise STDOUT
        if ($outfile) { $output | Out-File $outfile -Append}
        else { Write-Host $output }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I use [putty connection manager](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/scripts/puttycm.zip)  where you create a database of sessions. It's easy to copy and import that database to other computers.

See this [handy guide](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/03/putty-extreme-makeover-using-putty-connection-manager/)