# Putty is not running using schedule task

Tags: scheduled-tasks, putty

I am using Putty to transfer files from my windows machine to Linux machine.
I am able to transfer, when i run the script and also if i run the same script using Schedule task with my credentials.

if schedule the task to run using system account(SYSTEM)  or other user account, file transfer not happening.

Do i need to save any session vales?

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY saves session information in the registry for the current user only, this information will simply be not available for the other accounts you mentioned. So you either need to provide them by exporting yours and importing them in the other user's accounts or simply provide everything needed on the shell command invoked to copy your files. The latter sounds much easier to me in combination with a little script which gets invoked by the task scheduler.

Comment: Is there any steps that can export

Comment: There are different ways... Just use your search engine of choice with "putty export session". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-putty-sessions-list