# How to import sessions into MobaXterm?

Tags: windows, import, mobaxterm

I have to monitor many servers (over 3000) and the management has decided to use MobaXterm. All right, it works fine.

The ideal would be to have sessions already set up and shared with colleagues, it would be a considerable convenience.

Is there a way to massively import server data (name, ip, login) into sessions instead of insert them one by one?

Answer (score 15):

From the `Sessions` tab, left click `User sessions` and select `Import sessions from file`

[image: Import sessions from file]

The file should be similar to the following image.

[image]

The version is `Personal Edition v11.0`.

Comment: thanks
But my problem is a little different

I need a way to import over than 3000 session in a row.
I can't create one by one 3000+ session

But I undestanded that there's no way to do it

Comment: @LordMax I have import three sessions at once using this way, I can't see why you can't do the same.

Comment: I haven't undestood
I don't have the file.
I have to create the file and then import it.
I can't create one by one 3000+ session's file nor one with 3000+ session on it manually.

I need a way to create it via script and then import it in moba.
MAybe I find a way but's very hard to do cause moda don't give a way to know the SO of a machine directly and the format of the .session file is really a mess

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

MobaXterm is able to import sessions from a list of hosts, but this is limited to the import of hosts without users/port/passwords/advanced settings.
For that, you have to create a file with one server per line.

Then, in order to try this feature, you can start a local terminal and run the "ServersListToMxtSessions.sh" script.
The script will ask you to select a file, so just select the one you have created.

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 1):

MobaXterm is able to import sessions either from:

- The file in `.mxtsessions` format.

  You can export few examples first to see the syntax, so you can write a script to save it into that format.
- PuTTy/SuperPuTTy sessions.

  All sessions from PuTTy can be imported. [To import into PuTTy, you can create a registry file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13023920/55075).
- Other session formats (check the *contextual menu* in *Sessions* for full list).

Alternatively use a macro app to achieve that (such as [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)).

Comment: thanks,
I know that I can create a script, I'm just working on that, but it isn't a 'simple' nor 'immediate' solution. And the .mxtsessions format is really a mess
^__^

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To import mRemoteNG connections into MobaXterm, you need to export the mRemoteNG connections file in name "confCons.xml" specifically (Otherwise MobaXterm won't recognize it as potential file for import)

Once you have your mRemoteNG connections file named as "confCons.xml", go to:
MobaXterm -> Import sessions from third-party programs -> Import from MRemote sessions -> Choose the exported "confCons.xml"

Answer (score 0):

In MobaXTerm v23 you can choose Settings | Manage shared sessions. Save a session file, created with `Share these sessions with my team` to a secure location shared with your team and then establish a connection (shared, ftp, ssh, https) and you are set.

Sessions are automatically imported and configured.
Updates to the file are propagated to the team.