# delete worksheet from .xlsm file

Tags: excel, powershell, etl

I am trying to delete a named Worksheet from an `.xlsm` file.

I followed the example posted [here](http://pshscripts.blogspot.com/2010/03/new-excelworkbookps1.html) but it is not working for me. When I open the `.xlsm` file to check whether the Worksheet has been deleted, it is still there.

Here is my code:

```
$file2 = 'c:\file.xlsm' # destination's fullpath

$xl = new-object -c excel.application
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user

$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target

$sh2_wb2 = $wb2.sheets | where {$_.name -eq "myWorksheet"}
$sh2_wb2.delete() #Delete original sheet in template

$wb2.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:**

I changed my code to make the Excel Object visible when opening it. I then noticed that the `delete` call is being sent, but it is asking the user to confirm whether the delete should happen: `Data may exist in the sheet(s) selected for deletion. To permanently delete the data, press Delete.`

I then attempted to add a few more `displayAlerts = $false` in my code, but it is still giving me that prompt.

Here's my updated code, although it still does not work.

```
$file2 = 'c:\file.xlsm' # destination's fullpath

$xl = new-object -com excel.application -Property @{Visible = $true}
$xl.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user

$wb2 = $xl.workbooks.open($file2) # open target
$wb2.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user

$sh2_wb2 = $wb2.sheets | where {$_.name -eq "myWorksheet"}
$sh2_wb2.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user
$sh2_wb2.delete() #Delete original sheet in template

$wb2.close($true) # close and save destination workbook
$xl.quit()
spps -n excel
```

Comment: Your code works.  Do you have the rights to execute?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system  Also, you must have at least 1 visible sheet, so if myWorksheet is the only one visible, you will error.

Comment: You set me on the right track - please see my edit.

Comment: From your original code, if there is data on myWorksheet, and I set displayAlerts to $true, the sheet does not delete.  If displayAlerts is $false, the sheet deletes without issue.  This is Excel 2010 I am testing in.

Comment: I am also testing in Excel 2010. My original code was set to `displayAlerts = $false` and it still prompts me to delete the worksheet, even when it does not contain any data.

Comment: Is your file really in the root of C:\?  You need elevated rights, blah, blah, to save there.  My testing was done in a permissible folder.

Comment: No, it's in a personal dir that I have admin rights to.

Comment: Are you trying to delete the last worksheet in the workbook?  I tried this with Powershell and the worksheet does not get deleted.  However adding a 2nd worksheet, I was able to delete the named worksheet `Sheet1` by using `$del = $xlsWb.Sheets | where {$_.Name -eq 'Sheet1'}` then `$del.delete()`

Comment: Have you found an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its help for me :

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.add()
#working with sheets
$workbook.worksheets.item("Sheet1").Delete()
```