# Powershell Execution Policy is restricted, but only when run through python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, executionpolicy

I have a Windows Server 2008 box. I have run, as administrator, in powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted. When I run `powershell Get-ExecutionPolicy`, it returns Unrestricted.

I have created a .bat file which exhibits the issue I am seeing. The .bat file, test.bat, is only one line, `powershell Get-ExecutionPolicy`. When I open command prompt and run test.bat, "Unrestricted" is printed to the screen.

If I run the following python script however,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("test.bat")
```

"Restricted" is printed to the screen. How is this setting different when being run from Python's subprocess.Popen? I am not seeing the issue on a Windows 7 machine I have, where I have performed an identical workflow.

Comment: I found the answer. The Unrestricted ExecutionPolicy was for the 64-bit version of powershell. Python ends up calling the 32-bit version, which I had not set. Windows Server 2008 includes two versions of powershell, but Windows 7 does not.

Please see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system?rq=1
for more details

Comment: You can put that as an answer, and later accept it.

Comment: Yeah, but I had to wait 8 hours because my rep was too low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The Unrestricted ExecutionPolicy was for the 64-bit version of powershell. Python ends up calling the 32-bit version, which I had not set. Windows Server 2008 includes two versions of powershell, but Windows 7 does not.

Please see:
[PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system?rq=1)
for more details

Answer (score 2):

run following code in powershell as administrator

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```