# HDInsight Emulator takes up loads of memory; how to disable?

Tags: azure-hdinsight

I've installed the Azure HDInsight Emulator ("HortonWorks Data Platform 2.1.3.0 For Windows") on my 12Gb dev machine and it's taking all my RAM. I currently have 13 processes called 'Zulu Platform x64 Architecture', each between 170Mb and 75Mb .

Is this usual? Is there a way to disable it by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to uninstalling, there is a stop- and set-autostartoff .cmd file that can be used to control this inside the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, uninstalling "HortonWorks Data Platform 2.1.3.0 For Windows" gives me back my memory and removes all the 'Azure Hadoop' services and the 'Zulu Platform x64 Architecture' processes, and has re-stabilized my developer machine. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer provided by Matt, the folder where those scripts are located is C:\hdp.

The script to stop all services is `stop_local_hdp_services.cmd`. Just double-click it.

To disable auto start for all services, I had to open `Windows PowerShell` as Administrator and execute this two commands:

1. `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Reference: [Bypass warning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4038991/1454888)

2. `C:\hdp\set-onebox-manualstart.ps1`