# Cassandra Powershell Issue

Tags: windows, powershell, cassandra

I'm trying to start Cassandra on my Windows laptop and I'm seeing the following error:

```
WARNING! Powershell script execution unavailable
Please use 'powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted'
   on this user-account to run cassandra with fully featured
   functionality on this platform.
Starting with legacy startup options
Starting Cassandra Server
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

So I opened Powershell to try and set the ExecutionPolicy to Unrestricted and I get the following:

[image: error from powershell]

So I follow this to the registry entry which is described in the error and it seems the key is already set correctly. Am I just missing something obvious? The previous version of Cassandra ran perfectly on my machine, but ever since I updated, this is giving me all kinds of issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 6):

You must allow the execution of PowerShell Scripts on Windows 7.
The default execution policy of PowerShell is called Restricted. In this mode, PowerShell operates as an interactive shell only.

On **PowerShell** open ***C:\Windows\system32*** directory, and run the command

**Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted**

> Also, it’s a serious security risk if you forget to set the Execution
>   Policy back to Restricted mode.

So, in the same directory don'tforget to run

**Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted**

For detailed information [click here](https://www.howtogeek.com/106273/how-to-allow-the-execution-of-powershell-scripts-on-windows-7/)

Answer (score 1):

"Restricted" is the default policy.

Run the below command to get the policy

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser
```

Run the below to set unrestricted policy

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core

Answer (score 0):

I fix in windows by move from c:\ path(windows path) to other derive

After this I use
**cassandra -f**
And it work without any issue

I hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

even if on changing the windows execution policy you are getting error like
The argument `'C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\bin\bin\cassandra.ps1'` to the -File parameter does not exist. cassandra error

There might be a error in setting your JAVA_HOME
so explicitly set the JAVA_HOME by migrating into folder
`C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\bin`
then set `JAVA_HOME=%path` to your `jdk%`
in cassandra and node tool in windows batch file

even then if you get error like the shell is exciting then go to `C:\apache-cassandra-3.11.13\conf` then change the line just by inserting #in the front i.e #

```
$env:JVM_OPTS = "$env:JVM_OPTS -Djava.library.path=""$env:CASSANDRA_HOME\lib\sigar-bin"""
```

This worked for me!!

Answer (score -2):

By chance are you running the 64-bit powershell.exe but Cassandra is trying to use the 32-bit powershell.exe, or vice-versa?

"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

vs

"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

Comment: were you able to fix it by any luck ?

Answer (score -2):

You can go and change Xmx to lesser heap size.....
For e.g. search for JAVA_OPTS in CASSANDRA_HOME\bin\cassandra.bat file
......
set JAVA_OPTS=-ea^
 -javaagent:"%CASSANDRA_HOME%\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar"^
 **-Xms2G^

 -Xmx2G^**
......
***-Xms1G^

 -Xmx1G^***