# Azure PowerShell will not connect

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I have downloaded and installed the Azure Powershell by following the MS instructions:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/powershell-install-configure/

Using the Windows Powershell ISE I run the command:

**Login-AzureRmAccount**

which returns the the error:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount : The 'Login-AzureRmAccount' command was found in the module 'AzureRM.Profile', but the  module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module AzureRM.Profile'. At line:1 char:1
+ Login-AzureRmAccount
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Login-AzureRmAccount:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
```

**Import-Module AzureRM.Profile**

Returns this error:

```
Import-Module : File C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.Profile\CheckVersions.ps1 cannot be loaded 
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ Import-Module AzureRM.Profile
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Why is it so difficult to connect to Azure, what could be wrong?

Comment: what is the current `executionpolicy` on your system?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: Running scripts is disabled on your system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170

Answer (score 23):

From the command prompt run:

```
powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Comment: Is that supposed to run on Mac OS? I get `Set-ExecutionPolicy : Operation is not supported on this platform.`

Comment: on Mac OS,  it works like that `pwsh -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` check the help `pwsh -h`