# 'electron-packager' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: npm, electron, electron-packager

I recently started using electron. I have successfully completed the 1st phase by creating a hello world app (included files index.html, main.js, package.json). Now I am trying to package the app using electron-packager but getting this error

[image: electron-packager error]

Steps I have followed:

1. Created a project directory named helloworld.
2. Initialized the project directory using `npm init` command.
3. Then installed electron using `npm install electron --save-dev`.
4. Then created the javascript and html files as main.js and index.html respectively.
5. Then used `npm start` to execute the application.
6. Then installed electron-packager using `npm install electron-packager`.
7. Now the problem is coming in this step when i am trying to pacakge the app using command `electron-packager .`

Comment: npm install -g electron-packager

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Perform a global package install:

```sh
npm install -g electron-packager
```

The `-g` flag tells NPM to install the package globally which makes the command `electron-packager` available in your PATH.

---

If you don't want to do a global install you can install it locally and run with `npx`.

```sh
npm install -D electron-packager 

npx electron-packager .
```

---

Alternatively, you can reference it straight from the node_modules folder (not recommended).

```sh
./node_modules/electron-packager/cli.js
```

Answer (score 6):

There are two cases to make it work...

1. As discussed above, install electron globally using `-g`,

   i.e. using `npm install -g electron-packager`
2. Change in your `package.json`:

```
   "scripts": {
     "start": "electron-packager ."
   },
```

Then type in the command `npm start`.

This way it worked for me..

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed it locally with:

```
npm install electron-packager
```

Then, it's not gonna work, install it globally as a cli:

```
npm install -g electron-packager
```

You can also get it through:

```
"node_modules/electron-packager/cli.js" . --all --asar
```

After All, if you don't get it working, install electron-packager.
Then, go to your package.json. And beneath your start scripts. Make another string named "build" and give it a value of the electron-packager command you want to run:

```
...
    "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . --asar --all"
  },
...
```

Then, go in command prompt or terminal or bash.
Then, type:

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be totally off with it but my fix was that I put the dot without space just make sure in you package.json file its "start": "electron ."
Fixed it for me at least

Comment: Thank you!You absolutly right.I ignored space too and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You've to install electron-packager globally, that's why it shows `'electron-packager' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

For this, you have to install electron-package globally

You can install globally by using -g option.

Example:- 
`npm install -g electron-packager` **OR** `npm i -g electron-packager` //i stands for install

Answer (score 0):

In my case it doesn't worked after npm global installation.

On the electron-builder Readme page it's recommended to install with yarn.

```
Yarn is strongly recommended instead of npm.
yarn add electron-builder --dev
```

Also we can put folder directly to PATH. On Windows 10:

1. Search with word "environment" and open Edit the environment variables.
2. Select, edit and Add new value C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm to variable Path. Replace USER_NAME with your Windows username.

Then we might need to restart or logout.

Also in my case I enabled script execution on Windows 10 with instruction on answer below:

[PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)