# Install-PhpExtension command was found

Tags: php, powershell

I tried to install an extension with [powershell-phpmanager](https://github.com/mlocati/powershell-phpmanager)

But after install the manager with PowerShell I can't install extension for this exception. I didn't find any solution on github repository that's why I asked the question here.

Exception:

> Install-PhpExtension : The 'Install-PhpExtension' command was found in the module 'PhpManager', but the module could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module PhpManager'.

I also did to run `Import-Module PhpManager` then its showing,

> Import-Module : File C:\Users\Md. Emtiaz Zahid\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PhpManager\1.13.0.176\PhpManager.psm1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies
>   at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

If this issue is similar to someone and have any solution for that please let me know. Thanks

Comment: That PowerShell module is not part of PHP Manager for IIS, so you should not use the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solved]**

**Solution:**

I think there was some access permission issue in windows.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) i found some solution on that.

and then for my situation, i just run that command,

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
```

and its works!. But i dont know the meaning of this. if someone know detail about that please inform me about that. thanks