# I can't create a Vue project after installing Vue, what should I do?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

I installed vue but I can not create a Vue project, because the following error appears after running the command 'vue create project'. I am using S.O. windows 10 pro.

> Error:
>   vue: The file
>   C: \ Users \ leoca \ AppData \ Roaming \ npm \ vue.ps1 cannot
>   be loaded because the script execution was
>   disabled on this system. For more
>   For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
>   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
>   In line: 1 character: 1
>   + vue create calculator
>   + ~~~
>        + CategoryInfo: ErrodeSecurity: (:) []
>       , PSSecurityException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId: UnauthorizedAccess

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 6):

Run this in terminal:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
```

Answer (score -4):

you can download vue.js file and add it in your project like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vue.js"></script>
```

vue.js file link: https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js

Comment: This doesn't solve the fact that vue-cli isn't working on the OP's system.

Comment: Maybe he does not have administrative rights as there is unauthorized access error

Comment: Sorry guys, I formulated the wrong answer and then discovered the problem. I had inserted console.log () inside methods in Vue. Then a permission problem occurred in package.json. So I entered package.json, "eslintConfig" and "rules" and entered the following permission: "no-console": "off". For example: "rules": {"no-console": "off"},. Thank you so much for your personal help.