# how to set up a virtual environment in windows

Tags: python, windows, powershell, virtualenv

```
PS C:\Users\Hennessy\Desktop\brte_project\brte_project> env\Scripts\activate
env\Scripts\activate : File C:\Users\Hennessy\Desktop\brte_project\brte_project\env\Scripts\activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is 
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ env\Scripts\activate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

every time am trying to activate the virtual environment, vs code is giving me this error.What is the solution to this?

Comment: `cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system` - this is your error. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) you can find the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)