# I am trying to create react app but keeps on telling me unauthorized access

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
PS C:\Users\Bonnie_Py\Desktop\fullstack js>  create-react-app
react-app create-react-app : File C:\Users\Bonnie_Py Dev\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.ps1 
cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.  For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.

At line:1 char:2
 +  create-react-app react-app
 +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 6):

**Problem:**

This error comes when the PowerShell execution policy doesn’t allow us to run scripts. I also found the same error when tried to run a PowerShell script.

`PowerShell - running scripts is disabled on this system`

**Solution:**

If you do not have admin access, follow the below with command
=> "Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser".

The PowerShell execution policy is default set to Restricted. You can change the PowerShell execution policies with Set-ExecutionPolicy cmdlet. To run outside script set policy to RemoteSigned.

```
PS C:\> Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Below is the list of four different execution policies in PowerShell

**Restricted** – No scripts can be run.

**AllSigned** – Only scripts signed by a trusted publisher can be run.

**RemoteSigned** – Downloaded scripts must be signed by a trusted publisher.

**Unrestricted** – All Windows PowerShell scripts can be run.

You Should Also Know:

You can use get the current set execution policy in PowerShell.

```
PS C:\> get-executionpolicy
```

You can bypass this policy by adding -ExecutionPolicy ByPass when running PowerShell script.

```
c:\> powershell -ExecutionPolicy
```

Comment: Thank you.
This helped me.
The thing you missed is "Run the PowerShell window as an administrator" or else it will show error.