# not able to use vs code terminal despite setting the path

Tags: angular

[vs code terminal issues despite the directory path is been set][1]

[`ng : File C:\Users\vinay.c.goel\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this 
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ng g c course
+ ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess`1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ9XU.png

Comment: You have powershell selected in your terminal. Try switching to cmd

Comment: It's trying to run the script `ng.ps1` - `.ps1` being the extension for powershell scripts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system