# ES lint init setup not shown VS Code Windows OS

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code, configuration, eslint

I trying to set up the Eslint in VS Code IDE, however after installing the eslint dependency,
by `$ npm install eslint --save-dev` command then 
executing the below command for configuration

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init
```

getting the following error, what is the problem?

> eslint : File \AppData\Roaming\npm\eslint.ps1 cannot be
>   loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
>   information, see  about_Execution_Policies at
>   https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1
>   + eslint --init
>   + ~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your powershell you might need to execute

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Try

```
npx eslint --init
```

Also what is the output with

```
npm run eslint --init
```

Comment: Also this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: Thanks you so much.Now I can able to configure.