# Nodemon Command Not Working Unauthorized Access

Tags: javascript, nodemon

I'm trying to run nodemon, but when I do, it gives me the following error:

```
nodemon : File C:\Users\dyzha\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot 
be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For     
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon app.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityExcep  
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

I've tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, `npm install -g nodemon`, and `npm install nodemon --save-dev`.

Comment: Did you try reading the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system.
Can you try this?

Comment: im no windows expert, but my be run terminal as admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `Get-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`, it will change the `Get-ExecutionPolicy` to `RemoteSigned` and allow you to run Nodemon.

Comment: Should be `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, to resolve this:

- open the Windows PowerShell in Administration Mode
- type `Get-ExecutionPolicy` and press `Enter`

**If the machine returns "Restricted"**

- type `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestrict`and press `Enter`
- press: `y`

Now go to your terminal and try `nodemon` again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open Windows powerShell via cmd
cmd =>
`PowerShell_ISE`

in the Powershell Type this
PowerShell =>
`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
click `yes`

then try to open your `nodemon` again, it should be working well
Good luck