# Cannot create new project on angular

Tags: angular, typescript

> ng: File C:\Users\Dell-5559\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be
> loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more
> information, see about_Execution_Policies at
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. At line:1 char:1

What I did to solve this :

1. win +R past
   powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"
   2nd)In Windows 7:

Go to Start Menu and search for "Windows PowerShell ISE".

Right click the x86 version and choose "Run as administrator".

In the top part, paste Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; run the script. Choose "Yes".

Repeat these steps for the 64-bit version of Powershell ISE too (the non x86 version).

I'm just clarifying the steps that @Chad Miller hinted at. Thanks Chad!

3)As an Administrator, you can set the execution policy by typing this into your PowerShell window:

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned

didnot worked any.

Comment: what solutions from the article link have you tried?

Comment: You could easily get answer for this if you search google, this is not issue with angular CLI, most likely with your OS. You can try solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: In Windows 7:

Go to Start Menu and search for "Windows PowerShell ISE".

Right-click the x86 version and choose "Run as administrator".

In the top part, paste Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; run the script. Choose "Yes"  2nd option->powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope "CurrentUser" -ExecutionPolicy "RemoteSigned"   . i had tried this one .but did not worked@YegorAndrosov