# cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system when installing angular

Tags: javascript, angular, powershell, command-line-interface

I have downloaded nodejs (v14.16.0) on my pc and I tried to install angular using this command: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

But when I try to check the version of the angular using command `ng version` it is showing me this error:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: Hi @AjeetShah , I have got a little, but I am confused what command should I use for my problem.

Comment: I don't have windows and have less information, but I think I have used `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in the past.