# why nodemon is throwing some error in terminal?

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I am learning nodejs and came across nodemon. I installed nodemon using this command
`npm install -g nodemon` and it installed successfully but when i try to run nodemon using command `nodemon` then it through this error in command prompt.

```
nodemon : File C:\Users\callm\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ nodemon index.js
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Answer (score 0):

Using **RemoteSigned** as opposed to **Unrestricted**, and limiting the policy to the **CurrentUser** if possible.

Run Powershell as Admin, and then:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```