# I am getting the following problem at the time of ravendb installation

Tags: powershell, ravendb

At the time of ravendb installation when I am trying to run run.ps1 in windows powershell I am getting the following error. If any one knows the solution please help me.

```
PS D:\RavenDB> .\run.ps1
File D:\RavenDB\run.ps1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. 
Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:10
+ .\run.ps1 <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the [ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1) in PowerShell on your computer. The simplest fix is to run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` from an elevated PowerShell prompt and then execute `run.ps1`