# Powershell cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: windows, powershell, yarnpkg

My question related to yarn. Before when I start create projects I installed with npm.
After a long time when I want to start running with yarn it shows the following error:

```
yarn : File C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system.
```

(in Windows machine, Powershell)

Windows: 10

I tried with git bash terminal it worked!
but not in my powershell terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 14):

I have just fixed it by myself, anyway I am going to post answer here:

//open windows command Power shell as administrator and run command

1. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
2. `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code as administrator:

```
PowerShellSet-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```