# UnauthorizedAcess - Error while installing angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-cli

> ng add @angular/material
> ng : File C:\Users\welcome\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For
> more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
> At line:1 char:1

- ng add @angular/material
- ~~

  - CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess

Comment: do you work with a lan office pc?

Comment: no, I'm working with a personal laptop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `Command Prompt` as `administrator`
2. Run `cd <your-path-to-project>`
3. Run `ng add @angular/material`