# Unable to activate virtual environment

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Virtualenv is installed and created using `virtualenv venv` command.

However I am in same directory and can't activate it. Tried below commands

```
 venv/Scripts/activate
    . venv/Scripts/activate
    .venv\Scripts\activate
```

Please refer attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: did you try the advice provided in the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why but virual env can be activated on powershell best solution use cmd promt go in the file directry
and in the are are highlighted and type cmd and hit enter
[image]

now you can activate your virtual env by this method

Answer (score 0):

I hope recently installed Antivirus caused issue, however resolved as mentioned below

```
Start Windows PowerShell with the "Run as Administrator" option. 

Enable running unsigned scripts by entering:
```

**`set-executionpolicy remotesigned`**