# Nodemon cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

Can't start Nodemon due to error "...\nodemon.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system..."

Although the ExecutionPolicy is already set for the CurrentUser to "RemoteSigned":

```
    Scope ExecutionPolicy
    ----- ---------------
```

MachinePolicy       Undefined

UserPolicy       Undefined

Process       Undefined

CurrentUser    RemoteSigned

LocalMachine    Unrestricted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.