# Jest command not recognized

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i just started learning about Test Driven Developement and as an example i was asked to run the command `npm test helloWorld.spec.js` in the terminal but i got this error :

```
> javascript-exercises@1.0.0 test
> jest "helloWorld.spec.js"

'jest' n’est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.
// in english jest isn't recognized as an internal command or external
```

I'm working on windows and the only thing i have installed is node so what do i have to do?

Comment: Have you run `npm install`? Npm learns what to do when you run `npm test` from `package.json` (the `scripts` section). Also in the `package.json` file are listed the project dependencies (Jest is one of them, it seems) and `npm install` installs the project dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Choose one of the following methods

---

## 1) Install globally

You need to install `jest` globally:

```
npm install jest -g
```

*Note: You will have to call it as `jest something.spec.js` in your cli or specify a `test` command in your `package.json`.*

## 2) Install locally

Install `jest` locally with `npm install jest -D`.

You can use a `script` in your `package.json` called `test` which would be `"test": "jest"`.

- If any of the above don't work, try reinstalling `jest`.
- If it still doesn't work, try removing `node_modules` and `npm cache clean --force` and `npm install`

## 3) Config file

If you already have `jest` installed but it's not working, you can use a config file to track files based on **regex pattern** *(you can do a lot more if you check out the docs)*.

**The following part is from the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration):**

Jest's configuration can be defined in the `package.json` file of your project, or through a `jest.config.js`, or `jest.config.ts` file or through the `--config <path/to/file.js|ts|cjs|mjs|json>` option. If you'd like to use your `package.json` to store Jest's config, the `"jest"` key should be used on the top level so Jest will know how to find your settings:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true
  }
}
```

**Or through JavaScript:**

```
// Sync object
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const config = {
  verbose: true,
};

module.exports = config;

// Or async function
module.exports = async () => {
  return {
    verbose: true,
  };
};
```

**Or through TypeScript (if `ts-node` is installed):**

```
import type {Config} from '@jest/types';

// Sync object
const config: Config.InitialOptions = {
  verbose: true,
};
export default config;

// Or async function
export default async (): Promise<Config.InitialOptions> => {
  return {
    verbose: true,
  };
};
```

**When using the --config option, the JSON file must not contain a "jest" key:**

```
{
  "bail": 1,
  "verbose": true
}
```

### Regex options

**`testMatch` [array]**

`(default: [ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ])`

The glob patterns Jest uses to detect test files. By default it looks for `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `__tests__` folders, as well as any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`). It will also find files called `test.js` or `spec.js`.

*Note: Each glob pattern is applied in the order they are specified in the config. (For example ["!**/__fixtures__/**", "**/__tests__/**/*.js"] will not exclude __fixtures__ because the negation is overwritten with the second pattern. In order to make the negated glob work in this example it has to come after **/__tests__/**/*.js.)*

**`testRegex` [string | array]**

`Default: (/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.[jt]sx?$`

The pattern or patterns Jest uses to detect test files. By default it looks for `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `\_\_tests\_\_` folders, as well as any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`). It will also find files called `test.js` or `spec.js`. See also `testMatch` [array], but note that you cannot specify both options.

Comment: so i just did the first method and ran the command ` npm test....` it worked fine but when i tried yours `jest something.spec.js` it said running scripts is disactivated in this machine should i worry about it or just leave it as it is ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `powershell` maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system) will help

Answer (score 0):

you could add jest scripts on package.json

*or else*

you can use **npx** to access jest commands directly from the terminal i.e `npx jest`