# Powershell Execution Policies Restricted

Tags: powershell

How can solve this?

C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\sanity.ps1 cannot
be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this
system. For more information, see
about_Execution_Policies at
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1

- sanity init --coupon cleverprogrammer
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [],   
  PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
  ```

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: terminal powershell restricted. how can i unrestricted?

Comment: [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: Did you see `about_Execution_Policies` for more information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Check for `Get-ExecutionPolicy`  if it is like "AllSigned, Bypass, Default, Restricted, Undefined"
then execute the below command in PowerShell Administrator mode. You can also use   RemoteSigned, Unrestricted

`Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`