# error while trying to install yarn in vscode when i had earlier been using npm

Tags: reactjs

This is the error message

```
yarn : File C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1 cannot be loaded 
because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ yarn
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: This seems relevant: [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 3):

**For those who are not aware of how to solve this error using Windows PowerShell**

1. Open PowerShell (Run As Administrator)
2. Check the current execution policy using this command

```
    Get-ExecutionPolicy
    # You should get 'Restricted'
```

3. Run this command to make it 'Unrestricted'

```
  Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

4. Check again whether execution policy changed by running this command

   ```
   Get-ExecutionPolicy
   You should get 'Unrestricted'
   ```
5. Now try to run nodemon on your project

```
   nodemon 'filename.js'
```

Hope this would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Hello for solving this issue

- first run PowerShell in the administrator
  -be careful your path should be a current user
- run this command =>

Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

-Press A and Enter