# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask' and vitualenv Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded

Tags: python, flask, python-venv

I was trying to create a Flask app in my virtual environment on Windowns 10.

I've created the environment using `python -m venv flask_ven`

In VS code, `Python:Select Intrepreter`, I chose `Python 3.7.5("flask_evn":venv)`

I have a simple code to test the connection

```
from distutils.log import debug
from flask import Flask

app = Flask("mpg_prediction")  ## give it a name

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])  ## test if the app is working
def ping():
    return "Pinging Model Application!!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=9696)
```

But I tried to run it, it says flask is not installed.

I tried `pip freeze` in the terminal, then it says flask is installed `Flask==2.1.2`

I'm so puzzled.

When I was activating the virtual enviroment, I did come into an error

```
PS C:\Users\CSu.CL\Desktop\fuel consumption> & "c:/Users/CSu.CL/Desktop/fuel consumption/flask_env/Scripts/Activate.ps1"
& : File C:\Users\CSu.CL\Desktop\fuel consumption\flask_env\Scripts\Activate.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see 
At line:1 char:3
+ & "c:/Users/CSu.CL/Desktop/fuel consumption/flask_env/Scripts/Activat ...
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Has it got anything to do with not finding flask?

Comment: have you taken a look at this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Comment: pip install -U Flask

Comment: thank you @ShiladityaBose. It worked after I typed in 
```Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process```. 
It turned out that the env wasn't even activated.