# How to fix error while using sanity init coupon?

Tags: visual-studio, npm, sanity

I want to build a new project using sanity. I tried this command - `npm install -g @sanity/cli` and it was successfully installed. But when I tried this command - `sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022`, I get the following error:

```
sanity : File C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming\npm\sanity.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more 
information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ sanity init --coupon javascriptmastery2022
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Now how should I fix this error?

Comment: The link about execution policies appears to contain all the details you need to fix this. It's a PowerShell issue, not a Sanity one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 0):

Start powershell as administrator and go to the folder where you want to install sanity.
Type: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser`

Then change to `Unrestricted`

It should work now

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in bash in the backend Sanity folder