# I got this error when I starting Json server in VS CODE (json-server --watch db.json) but its working CMD

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, json-server

```
json-server : File C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Roaming\npm\json-server.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this 
system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ json-server --watch db.json
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Comment: You need to set execution policies. I think this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system

Answer (score 2):

Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. cd/*your vs code file*
2. npm install -g json-server
3. npx json-server --watch *api/db.json* *your file .json* api.db.json mine ..