# Running a text as powershell scripts

Tags: powershell

I have to run my powershell scripts ONLY with these way:

```
Get-Content "ScriptName.ps1" -raw | powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy byPass -NoExit -Command -
```

It works ok with some scripts but others cannot be executed with these way, even if they work from PowerShell ISE, or Visual Studio code. Executing ends without any output or warnings.

For me, it looks like when we run raw text as a Command for powershell.exe some symbols or commands don't work the same way as we run .ps1 script from ISE or VS code. I cannot find the rules for Execution scripts like these. Could someone help me with the rules, what i need to do with any script before i wanna run it like these?

I have tried escaping special characters with "/" but it doesnt work

Comment: Try setting WorkingDirectory.  The script may need to be run from a specific folder.   See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3

Comment: Ty for your answer, but specifying WorkDirectory didn't help =(

Comment: "I have to run my powershell scripts ONLY with these way" - why? What's the purpose?

Comment: I assume this is because of a domain policy in place - why not ask your domain admin to create a group policy which allows unsigned scripts for certain users?

Comment: Im writing scripts for big system which, unfortunately, can execute it only in way like these. I found only one rule for these way of executing: after "}" always have to be a space or new string, but it's still not enough, coz still not all scripts can be executed. Help for "powershell.exe" command is : " If the value of Command is "-", the command text is read from standard input." But nothing about format of that input. I'm sure, that there have to be more complex instruction, but i can't find nothing more about

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell's execution policy is a safety feature that controls the conditions under which PowerShell loads configuration files and runs scripts.

Script editors run PS commands as if you typed them into the console, therefore don't trigger the execution policy in most cases.

Rather than trying to bypass the execution policy this way you should either sign your scripts or put in place a domain policy which allows the script to be run normally.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Scepticalist's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75221469/45375):

- If a GPO (Group Policy Object) on your system prevents execution of your scripts, `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will *not* be able to override that.
- *Without* a GPO in place, running e.g. `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force` as a *one-time* action should suffice, after which you'll be able to run (local) scripts *directly* in the context of your account.

---

In other words: if a GPO is the problem, `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` will have no effect, and executing your script's *content* as a workaround will only succeed if its code doesn't try to call *other* scripts or script-based modules / modules with configuration data - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71564847/45375) for a comprehensive overview of PowerShell's [execution policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies).

A **solution** to your problem:

- If you want to **run your script's code in a *child* process** (this assumes that you're calling *from PowerShell*, because only then is passing a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) supported - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77085105/45375) for background:

  ```
  powershell.exe ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content ScriptName.ps1 -Raw)))
  ```

  - To also pass - invariably *positional* - arguments, use `-args`  with an *array* of arguments (e.g. `... -args foo, 42`)
- If you want to **run it *in-process*** (note that [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) is otherwise [best avoided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/avoid-using-invoke-expression)):

  ```
  Invoke-Expression (Get-Content ScriptName.ps1 -Raw)
  ```

  - To also pass - potentially also *named* - *arguments*, you again need a script block; pass arguments individually, as usual:

    ```
    & ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content ScriptName.ps1 -Raw))) foo 42
    ```
  - The **caveat** in both these in-process calls is that if your script file's code terminates with `exit`, the *calling* session will exit too.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Using [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, or [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, with `-Command -` has quirks and limitations, summarized in [GitHub issue #3223](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3223).
- In short, it exhibits pseudo-interactive behavior, runs each statement in its own pipeline, and requires *two* newlines at the end of the input in order to ensure that multiline statements are reliably executed.