# Passing Hashtable Parameter from CommandLine PowerShell 7.2

Tags: powershell, hashtable, powershell-7.2

I am trying to create a PowerShell script, and one of the parameters of the script is a Hashtable. I am using PowerShell 7.2 for this project, and whenever I try to pass a Hashtable in through the command line, it passes it as the string `System.Collections.Hashtable` instead of the Hashtable itself. This causes the script to throw an error as the parameter is types as a Hashtable.

Here is a shortened version of the script I have written.

```
#requires -version 7.2

[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $False)]
param ([hashtable] $TestTable)

$TestTable
```

I have tried the following command in the PowerShell command line.
`pwsh .\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = "This is a test"}`
`pwsh -Command .\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = "This is a test"}`
And many variants of these attempting different combinations of commas, quotes, brackets, and @ symbols.

When I run either of the two commands listed above I get the error `ScriptName.ps1: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'TestTable'. Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.Hashtable".`

I am trying to stick with PowerShell 7.2 for the project. When I remove the requirement for 7.2 and run the command without pwsh, it works perfectly, but I have not been able to find a solution that works for 7.2. If anyone knows how to do this, I would greatly appreciate an explanation.

Comment: quote the command: `pwsh -c '.\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = "This is a test"}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried the following command in the *PowerShell command line*.

There's usually no good reason to call [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, *from PowerShell*, given that you can invoke `.ps1` files *directly, in-process*:

```bash
.\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = "This is a test"}
```

If you want to call via the CLI nonetheless (e.g. to confine to a *child process* any session-level changes a (potentially ill-behaved) script may make), use a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`) for your invocation:

```bash
pwsh { .\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = "This is a test"} }
```

Note:

- Passing a *script block* only works *from inside PowerShell*,

  - There, its use *implies* the `-Command` (`-c`) CLI parameter

    - However, from *outside* PowerShell - in which case the command to execute must be passed as a *string* (see below) - use of `-Command` (`-c`) is *required*, because `-File` is the default in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) (unlike in *Windows PowerShell*).
  - If you want to pass *arguments* to the script block (usually based on the *caller's* values), follow the script-block argument with an `--args` argument that is an array of positional arguments that the script block should see, by default via the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args); e.g.:

    ```bash
    pwsh { "$($args.Count) args received."; $args } -args foo, bar
    ```
- Calling from *outside* PowerShell requires that you comply with the syntax requirements of the *calling shell* in order to pass the `"` chars. that are part of the PowerShell command to executed through:

  - From `cmd.exe` (Windows)

    ```bash
    pwsh -Command ".\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = \"This is a test\"}"
    ```
  - From POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash (on Unix-like platforms):

    ```bash
    pwsh -Command '.\ScriptName.ps1 -TestTable @{Test = "This is a test"}'
    ```

    - Note that while the `"...\"...\"..."` approach would work as well in principle, commands containing `$` chars. would require those to be `\`-escaped as well in order to be passed through. On the plus side, *not* escaping them allows you to *embed* variable values *from the caller* in the command (the equivalent approach from `cmd.exe` on Windows would be to use `%...%` variable references).
- As for what output a *caller* to PowerShell's CLI receives:

  - When calling from *inside PowerShell* using a *script block*:

    - Type fidelity is *maintained*, but *with limitations*, namely the ones imposed by PowerShell's *cross-process serialization*: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).
  - Otherwise (when calling *from outside PowerShell* / using a *string* to pass the command):

    - All outputs are *strings* (text), using the character encoding implied by the console window's code page (as reflected in `[Console]::OutputEncoding` inside PowerShell).
    - Complex objects - e.g. the [`System.IO.FileSystemInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileSystemInfo) that [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) outputs - are represented by their *for-display* string representations, as they would print to the display from inside an interactive PowerShell session.
    - The only way to produce *structured* text output is to pass `-OutputFormat xml` (`-of xml`), which results in [CLIXML](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-psrp) output, i.e the XLM-based format that PowerShell itself uses for cross-process serialization; however, outside of PowerShell there aren't any well-known libraries that can consume this format.